# Who Wants to Win a LaTeX Book?

Tags: discussion, publicity

I am organising a lottery and Springer have kindly agreed to donate a copy of [*LaTeX and Friends*](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html).

Joseph Wright has kindly agreed to act a an independent witness/judge and he knows the winning number.

`<LEGAL STUFF>` The lottery closes when the judges announce the winner. The judges decision is final and there shall be no discussion
and or correspondence about the outcome of the lottery.  `</LEGAL STUFF>`

To win the book you must guess a number in the range 1--200.  The first person who guesses the right number wins the book.  Please note that the time of *arrival* in TeX-SX is what counts, not the time of sending.

To give everybody a fair chance, you may submit only one number.

There is one exception to the previous rule. If several contestants submit the same number, the contestant whose submission arrived first is valid. The other contestants may resubmit a new number.

Contestants must have been a member of TeX-SX before 13 December, 2012. (Without this restriction, people may start creating fake accounts and submit multiple guesses.)

Please post your guess as an *answer* to this meta question; not as a comment. Comments will be ignored. Please only put your guess in the body of the answer.

Guesses will be checked every couple of days and the winner will be announced within a few days after.

**EDIT: At the winner's request, I can sign the book. (I'm not doing this by default because I know some people want to keep their books pencil and ink free.)**

**EDIT: There are still plenty of free numbers. I am relaxing the rules. Contestants may submit 2 (valid) guesses.**

**EDIT: Congratulations to @seadoor for guessing the right number 132. Well done. Thanks to Joseph Wright for helping as a judge and alerting me the right number had been chosen (I hadn't noticed it because it was added as an edit to an existing post). Thanks to everybody for participating. It took a bit longer than anticipated. Next time I should allow a shorter range of numbers.**

Finally, please accept my apologies for entering the `publicity` tag.

Have fun.

Marc van Dongen

---

The numbers that are already chosen : *Running `your favorite algorithm`-sort... Please Wait...*

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
41
42
43
45
47
49
50
51
52
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
64
65
66
67
68
69
71
72
73
74
75
77
78
80
81
83
84
85
87
88
89
91
92
96
97
98
99
100
101
102
105
106
108
109
110
111
112
113
114
116
117
118
119
120
121
122
123
124
125
126
127
128
129
130
131
132
133
135
136
137
138
139
142
143
144
145
147
149
150
151
152
153
154
156
157
160
161
162
164
165
166
167
169
170
171
172
173
174
176
177
180
182
183
185
187
188
190
191
193
195
196
197
198
199
200
250

```
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|040|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|044|◖■◗|046|◖■◗|048|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|053|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|063|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|070|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|076|◖■◗|◖■◗|079|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|082|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|086|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|090|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|093|094|095|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|103|104|◖■◗|◖■◗|107|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|115|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|134|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|140|
-----------------------------------------
|141|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|146|◖■◗|148|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|155|◖■◗|◖■◗|158|159|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|168|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|175|◖■◗|◖■◗|178|179|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|181|◖■◗|◖■◗|184|◖■◗|186|◖■◗|◖■◗|189|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------
|◖■◗|192|◖■◗|194|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
-----------------------------------------


                                    |◖■◗|
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\def\transformtime#1-#2-#3 #4:#5!{
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
    \pgfmathparse{#3+#4/24+#5/(24*60)-24}
    \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
}

\pgfplotsset{
    timeplot zero/.initial=0,
    timeplot/.style={
        x coord trafo/.code={\expandafter\transformtime##1!},
        x coord inv trafo/.code={%
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\days{floor{##1+23}}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\hours{(##1+23-\days)*24+24}
            \def\pgfmathresult{\days\ Dec}
            \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}
        },
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xticklabel=\tick
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xcomb,
    timeplot,
    x tick label as interval,
    axis on top,
    xmin=2012-12-13 17:59,
    xmax=2012-12-20 24:00,
    xtick={2012-12-13 17:59, 2012-12-14 0:0.01, 2012-12-15 0:0.01, 2012-12-15 24:00.01, 2012-12-16 24:00.01, 2012-12-17 24:00.01, 2012-12-18 24:00.01, 2012-12-19 24:00.01, 2012-12-20 24:00.01},
    ymin=0, ymax=200,
    width=18cm, height=12cm,
    clip=false,
    extra x ticks={2012-12-13 17:59},
    after end axis/.code={
        \draw (axis cs:2012-12-13 17:59,0) -- (axis cs:2012-12-13 17:59,205) node [inner xsep=0pt, anchor=south west, align=left] {Lottery announced};
        \draw (axis cs:2012-12-17 7:10,0) -- (axis cs:2012-12-17 7:10,205) node [inner xsep=0pt, anchor=south west, align=left] {Relaxed rules:\\two votes allowed};
    }
]
\addplot +[draw=gray!50, mark options={black}, line width=12cm/200] table [col sep=comma] {
Time, Value
2012-12-13 18:22, 42
2012-12-13 18:28, 97
2012-12-13 18:56, 84
2012-12-13 18:58, 117
2012-12-13 19:07, 128
2012-12-13 19:11, 49
2012-12-13 19:19, 137
2012-12-13 19:21, 13
2012-12-13 19:22, 127
2012-12-13 19:28, 250
2012-12-13 19:43, 3
2012-12-13 21:43, 1
2012-12-13 21:47, 67
2012-12-13 22:02, 121
2012-12-13 22:13, 2
2012-12-13 22:29, 39
2012-12-13 22:42, 28
2012-12-13 23:07, 156
2012-12-13 23:27, 73
2012-12-13 23:34, 154
2012-12-13 23:39, 21
2012-12-13 23:55, 43
2012-12-14 0:04, 123
2012-12-14 0:27, 113
2012-12-14 1:12, 66
2012-12-14 1:26, 100
2012-12-14 2:12, 142
2012-12-14 2:31, 17
2012-12-14 2:43, 78
2012-12-14 3:53, 111
2012-12-14 5:38, 12
2012-12-14 7:21, 33
2012-12-14 8:50, 200
2012-12-14 8:52, 29
2012-12-14 9:00, 91
2012-12-14 9:21, 149
2012-12-14 9:25, 69
2012-12-14 9:39, 85
2012-12-14 10:23, 10
2012-12-14 10:36, 8
2012-12-14 11:11, 22
2012-12-14 11:13, 109
2012-12-14 11:45, 191
2012-12-14 12:04, 31
2012-12-14 13:14, 172
2012-12-14 15:56, 131
2012-12-14 14:29, 30
2012-12-14 15:44, 18
2012-12-14 17:06, 144
2012-12-14 17:24, 138
2012-12-14 17:50, 88
2012-12-14 19:47, 177
2012-12-14 20:17, 60
2012-12-14 20:34, 199
2012-12-14 20:51, 27
2012-12-14 21:05, 23
2012-12-14 22:51, 11
2012-12-14 23:48, 101
2012-12-15 1:14, 35
2012-12-15 1:20, 7
2012-12-15 3:16, 119
2012-12-15 4:33, 57
2012-12-15 4:42, 96
2012-12-15 6:13, 170
2012-12-15 9:00, 15
2012-12-15 13:59, 61
2012-12-15 14:58, 167
2012-12-15 16:43, 98
2012-12-15 17:13, 139
2012-12-15 18:15, 110
2012-12-15 18:25, 64
2012-12-15 20:33, 71
2012-12-15 20:46, 58
2012-12-15 23:03, 19
2012-12-16 10:02, 139
2012-12-16 11:34, 99
2012-12-16 13:56, 38
2012-12-16 14:56, 16
2012-12-16 17:42, 47
2012-12-16 18:29, 185
2012-12-16 19:34, 150
2012-12-16 20:45, 9
2012-12-17 6:01, 106
2012-12-17 7:45, 102
2012-12-17 7:50, 81
2012-12-17 7:50, 37
2012-12-17 8:20, 24
2012-12-17 8:20, 54
2012-12-17 8:23, 197
2012-12-17 8:23, 135
2012-12-17 8:36, 160
2012-12-17 8:46, 72
2012-12-17 8:54, 32
2012-12-17 9:52, 9
2012-12-17 10:8, 171
2012-12-17 12:07, 36
2012-12-17 12:20, 120    
2012-12-17 13:20, 169
2012-12-17 13:41, 6
2012-12-17 14:00, 182
2012-12-17 14:38, 163
2012-12-17 14:38, 188
2012-12-17 15:06, 187
2012-12-17 15:52, 129
2012-12-17 16:22, 4
2012-12-17 16:22, 5
2012-12-17 17:07, 80
2012-12-17 17:07, 166
2012-12-17 17:10, 162
2012-12-17 17:22, 55
2012-12-17 17:57, 105
2012-12-17 19:18, 14
2012-12-17 19:34, 147
2012-12-17 19:42, 34
2012-12-17 19:42, 157
2012-12-17 19:55, 112
2012-12-17 20:17, 183
2012-12-17 20:17, 45
2012-12-17 20:20, 198
2012-12-17 20:59, 87
2012-12-17 21:30, 20
2012-12-17 21:51, 116
2012-12-17 22:01, 77
2012-12-17 22:01, 145
2012-12-17 22:35, 133
2012-12-17 22:35, 51
2012-12-17 22:40, 180
2012-12-17 23:30, 151
2012-12-18 3:14, 161
2012-12-18 4:14, 105
2012-12-18 4:14, 106
2012-12-18 4:32, 195
2012-12-18 4:32, 196
2012-12-18 8:45, 190
2012-12-18 10:43, 108
2012-12-18 13:59, 89
2012-12-18 16:11, 65
2012-12-18 16:25, 164
2012-12-18 22:03, 173
2012-12-18 22:03, 174
2012-12-18 23:37, 136
2012-12-19 1:32, 130
2012-12-19 3:5, 75
2012-12-19 3:29, 62
2012-12-19 4:0, 68
2012-12-19 7:58, 125
2012-12-19 9:46, 83
2012-12-19 10:16, 41
2012-12-19 11:29, 92
2012-12-19 11:29, 114
2012-12-19 12:27, 122
2012-12-19 15:9, 143
2012-12-19 15:14, 152
2012-12-19 15:14, 153
2012-12-19 19:53, 74
2012-12-19 20:32, 52
2012-12-19 23:9, 126
2012-12-20 0:21, 50
2012-12-20 10:12, 59
2012-12-20 10:15, 165
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To all: After posting the answer can you please include your number on the list in the question ? If we expect high attendance it will soon go out of hand. Maybe we can collect all the guesses in one answer for ease similar to our package maintainers question.

Comment: @percusse - Newbies can't edit the question :(

Comment: @Tyler No problem, I added the number :)

Comment: @percusse could you please update my magic number as well

Comment: What happens if there are < 200 entries and the number you choose hasn't been picked by anyone?

Comment: @percusse yes, thanks a lot

Comment: @AlanMunn Should there not be a winner by Christmas, I'll come up with a solution. Possible solutions are picking a contestant at random. (It's possible.)

Comment: I think we need a comma to separate the list elements.

Comment: FYI There's another book for grabs on `comp.text.tex`.

Comment: I wonder why 108 is still not taken... `:P`

Comment: I can't help but wonder what the purpose of the lottery is.

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog The purpose of the lottery is to give away a book for free.

Comment: @TimParenti I suggest that if you're only interested in updating the list of numbers and couldn't be bothered with the graph, you don't edit this question. People have worked hard to keep the data consistent and efforts like yours will ruin this. Also, the rules _clearly_ state that participants must have been a member of TeX.SX before 13 December, which you never were. (With the question now being a community WIKI I am not going to enforce this rule.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen In my defense: **(1)** I followed the suggestion to add my own number to the list and, before editing, checked the last several revisions before mine. Since the list and graph seemed to be maintained separately, I explicitly mentioned that I didn't update the graph _as a courtesy_ to alert those actively maintaining it. Clearly that worked; my apologies if it offended. **(2)** I have been a member at TeX.SX since 17 January 2012 and am not sure how you determined otherwise. **(3)** I've submitted my second entry and updated the graph accordingly this time.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I didn’t add my guess to the graph, too. Like Tim I thought, this is done by someone with a script. And on a deeper look I see, also others didn’t update the graph function.

Comment: oh no! 14 was missed somehow!! *succumbs to OCD and re-tabulates*

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I *did* update the graph regarding my second entry, but I'm in doubt about which time zone to use. Probably not my local time, but which zone instead?

Comment: @Stephen It seems the graph is done in UTC according to the time the entry was posted here.

Comment: I do not know how, Jake does it, but with http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/meta.tex.stackexchange/questions/2982/answers?body=false&sort=creation&order=asc&pagesize=100&page=1 and http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/meta.tex.stackexchange/questions/2982/answers?body=false&sort=creation&order=asc&pagesize=100&page=2 you get the posting time (in my Firefox shown in my local timezone). For some edited answers you can do it separately (replace `{id}` by the real id number): `http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/meta.tex.stackexchange/answers/{id}/?body=false&sort=activity&order=asc`.

Comment: @TimParenti: Yup, the graph is in UTC. I used the time displayed when I hover over the `posted 3 hours ago` text.

Comment: @Jake Oh, I didn’t know that! Obviously my mouse never was long enough over the time indication. BTW in the given links above to stack2rss.stackexchange.com one can also say `sort=activity` instead of `sort=creation`.

Comment: @Jake , Hi, Kindly do me a favour by updating my second choice (**161**) as i am afraid to touch the graph and data after lot of hardwork put in? Thank you so much

Comment: @TimParenti I am sorry. I checked your profile and couldn't find any evidence of activity in TeX.SX, which is what made me make the statement about membership.

Comment: @Stephen I do not maintain the graph because I don't want to introduce errors. I don't know about the time zone.

Comment: @all thanks for maintaining the graph and the table.

Comment: Could someone please update the graph, I updated the code, but I can not compile it. Thanks.

Comment: So those who come to enter now stand a much higher change than those of us who have entered already, because there are fewer numbers left for them to choose from :( But I guess we had the chance earlier on to guess before they did.

Comment: @SabreWolfy Ohh time for everyone to play [Monty Hall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_Problem)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Member ≠ Active ≠ Active on Meta.  But alas, I didn't win, so it's moot.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Wow, has the lucky number not been chosen yet? Or are you waiting until all numbers have been selected before you announce which one won?

Comment: @Jake We have a winner.

Comment: Is there some meaning to 132, or was it chosen randomly?

Comment: @mafp It was chosen at random. I sent the number to Joseph Wright before I announced the lottery.

Comment: __“Next time?”__

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel As a figure of speech:)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about 57 - after the famous Legend?

*Edited to add my next choice:* **132**

[image: The prize:-]

Comment: Congratulations. If you let me know about a delivery address, I'll send the book to you. Do you want the book signed?

Comment: BTW 132 Was the right choice.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Thanks for being very kind and offering this free book. I'd be pleased to have it signed! How do I contact you?

Comment: @seadoor Feel free to contact me via my regular email address, which you may find if you go to my TeX.SX profile, and then visit myhomepage.

Answer (score 23):

127 - Last Mersenne prime less than 200. `:)`

> Friends, if I can talk to all of you for a moment: so far, we have 68 answers, but only 37 upvotes in the main "question". To be honest, I was expecting the same number of answers and upvotes. IMHO if you took the time to add an entry in order to win the LaTeX book, you should upvote Marc's main thread as a *thank you note* for him being so kind in offering one copy of his book to a member here. Please, don't be greedy. We should participate here as a community, not like a bunch of people wanting freebies. `:(`

Comment: You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 15):

250 (could never do this math stuff)

Comment: It is beyond the scope of the permitted interval.

Answer (score 13):

42 - if it's not [the answer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_%28Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy%29), then the question is wrong. ;-)

Second guess: 147, because it was not taken before.

Answer (score 11):

191 - to be near the top end of the range.

PS I have read *all* the other answers thoroughly and believe my answer adds useful extra information that can't be placed in a comment.

PPS This must be the question attracting the highest number of incorrect answers on this site.

Answer (score 11):

I would like to ask my random number generator (see below), but since 9 is already taken, I will go for

**4 & 5** since 4+5=9 almost surely.

[image: dilbert]

Answer (score 10):

**131**; I'm a random number generator myself and this is the result.

Also another generator agrees;

[image]

I have generated another one which is 68. **Oops sorry never mind that it was after deadline.**

Comment: What deadline do you mean? I thought the lottery runs until Christmas?

Comment: @Jake Hahaha, I didn't actually read the question properly but saw your deadline in the plot. So nevermind^2 hahaha, sometimes I amaze myself.

Comment: Oh my, Rain Man was so close. I blame quantum physics for rounding the algorithm to 132 instead of 131. `:)`

Comment: The mistake was to generate a random number instead of the winning one.

Answer (score 9):

```
     888888888          888888888     
   88:::::::::88      88:::::::::88   
 88:::::::::::::88  88:::::::::::::88 
8::::::88888::::::88::::::88888::::::8
8:::::8     8:::::88:::::8     8:::::8
8:::::8     8:::::88:::::8     8:::::8
 8:::::88888:::::8  8:::::88888:::::8 
  8:::::::::::::8    8:::::::::::::8  
 8:::::88888:::::8  8:::::88888:::::8 
8:::::8     8:::::88:::::8     8:::::8
8:::::8     8:::::88:::::8     8:::::8
8:::::8     8:::::88:::::8     8:::::8
8::::::88888::::::88::::::88888::::::8
 88:::::::::::::88  88:::::::::::::88 
   88:::::::::88      88:::::::::88   
     888888888          888888888
```

Comment: Should I bother to zoom in for the fractals?

Comment: Please up vote up to 8.

Comment: I know that someone has down voted this answer from 9 to 8.

Comment: -1 because I want the vote count to be eight :)

Answer (score 8):

**118**, and if you *really* wanna know why:

- `L` is the 12th letter of the alphabet
- `a` is the first letter of the alphabet
- `T` is the 20th letter of the alphabet
- `e` is the 5th ... I think you've guessed the logic behind this by now
- `X` -> 24

So: `12 + 1 + 20 + 5 + 24 = 62`.

But because we wouldn't wanna miss the fact that `L`, `T` and `X` are capitals, they count double, and `24 + 1 + 40 + 5 + 24 = 118`, that's what I'll go for.

(Also, have you noticed that the small letters in LaTeX come early in the alphabet, and therefore have a low number, and the caps are late in the alphabet and therefore have a high number? And that the letter whose pronunciation is probably the most debated in the TeX community also has the highest number? And that the letter with the lowest number in the alphabet is also the letter with the lowest height in the typographical `\LaTeX{}`? Truly kabbalistic!)

Comment: Actually, `Τ` (Tau) is the 19th letter, `Ε` (Epsilon) the fifth and `Χ` (Chi) the 22nd letter of the Greek alphabet.

Answer (score 7):

172 (and yes, dear Stackexchange system, I did "read through all the answers" to make sure I'm contributing "something new"...)

Second guess: 182 (it's got to be up here somewhere)

Answer (score 6):

121 -- the first palindromic square of an integer.

Comment: What about 0, 1, 4, and 9?

Comment: I don't really count one-letter words as palindroms :) But yes, You have got a good point ...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen `\epsilon`, the empty word, is the representation of the number `0`, and it is the unique shortest palindrome ;)

Answer (score 6):

78 because Knuth released TeX in '78

Answer (score 6):

111

Is a quirky comment necessary in order to win? I don't have one :(

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that 111 is a perfect totient number. `:)`

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\Huge 33 % I should be the winner!
\end{document}
```

Note: [According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/33_%28number%29):

> 33 (thirty-three) is a special natural number following 32 and preceding 34.

My second choice is [62 (sixty two)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3106/19356).

Comment: If I win, please give me the e-book version rather than the printed version because I have no permanent address.

Answer (score 6):

```
ipython
In [1]: from random import randrange
In [2]: randrange(200)
Out[2]: 109
```

109

```
ipython
In [1]: from random import randrange
In [2]: x = 1
In [3]: s = set([1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21, 22, 23, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 33, 35, 37, 38, 39, 42, 43, 47, 49, 57, 58, 60, 61, 64, 66, 67, 69, 71, 73, 78, 81, 84, 85, 88, 91, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 106, 109, 110, 111, 113, 117, 118, 119, 121, 123, 127, 128, 131, 135, 137, 138, 139, 142, 144, 149, 150, 154, 156, 167, 170, 172, 177, 185, 191, 193, 197, 199, 200])
In [4]: while x in s:
            x = randrange(200)
In [5]: x
Out[5]: 72
```

72

Comment: Was it luck that this number wasn't already taken?  Or is `python` really as good as they tell us?

Answer (score 6):

30

The clue must be inside of that book, `LaTeX and Friends`! But how would I know if I don't have it? It must be the total number of pages or how many chapters. Or how many coffee stains Joseph and Marc have in theirs... This is getting too difficult.

Comment: Did you know there is a LaTeX package to create coffee stains in your document? http://hanno-rein.de/archives/349

Comment: @Vivi Great! LaTeX ought to incorporate this package so that all projects produce a good percentage of coffee stains throughout the PDF's by default. This package is essential.

Answer (score 6):

Pi.  It's between 1 and 200, and I don't think the question said it has to be an integer.

Comment: But you have to *guess* a number so it's at least a rational number.

Comment: Not sure why I can't guess $\pi$ just as easily as any other number.

Comment: If I give you another sufficiently long number, would you be able to distinguish that it is pi or not? If yes you win I'll buy the book for you. If not, how can you guess a number if you don't know the digits?

Comment: I wouldn't be able to distinguish it by its approximate decimal representation, but there are many ways to describe a number.

Answer (score 5):

2 - I would have said 42 but @Stephen beat me to it ... and 3 as in LaTeX3 is taken too so I go with 2 as in LaTeX2e

Comment: You also can't go wrong with the oddest of all the prime numbers.

Answer (score 5):

my wild guess is based on the

hard cover (ISBN 978-3-642-238-**154**)

eBook (ISBN 978-3-642-238-**161**)

154- is my first choice.

161- is my second choice

Answer (score 4):

28 - it's a perfect number :-)

Answer (score 4):

43

> Cinque, dieci, venti, trenta,
>   trentasei, quarantatré

The immortal opening words of "Le nozze di Figaro" (The marriage of Figaro).

Answer (score 4):

**85** because "*LaTeX was first developed in **1985** by [Leslie Lamport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leslie_Lamport)* " - according to http://www.latex-project.org/intro.html **:)**

**EDIT**: 2nd number = **136**. Because: **(A)** It is one of the few still available -**AND**- **(B)** (/me searches frantically for something LaTeX related)... is the number of pages formatted for on-line viewing of "Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis" by Nicola L.C. Talbot, freely available (GNU Free Documentation License) at http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/thesis/thesis.html - which will be a great read if I don't win this lottery!  **;-)**

**EDIT #2**: I just edited the question to add my second guess (136) to the several parts of the question (number list, number table and LaTeX source code for the graph). My first guess was already in the question (thanks to the one who added it). I hope I did it right! **:)**

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to *improve* one of the existing answers I have decided to post the obviously correct answer and that is **177**.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

Is this a quiz? Anyway, I'm taking 170 which is the age of Springer Verlag :-)

Answer (score 3):

84 - as it doubles *the answer*.

Answer (score 3):

So this is my first post on meta - who would have guessed that? Here we go: 117 and 36

Answer (score 3):

128 -- can't go higher with a power of 2.

Answer (score 3):

- **49**
- **151**

Comment: And it is `49 = 42 + 7`. I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 3):

137 - just because that's the first number that came to mind.

Answer (score 3):

1 - just in case no-one remembers to answer this one.

Answer (score 3):

91​​​​

Answer (score 3):

22

Answer (score 3):

144 - It has a number of interesting properties; the one I like the most: the largest Fibonacci number that is a square.

EDIT: my second guess: 55 - The largest triangular number in the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2):

97 - why not! (This is just to get the answer registered)

Answer (score 2):

I choose 3, because of [this comment](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7260159#7260159).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

67 -- just a random number ...

My second guess: 120.

Answer (score 2):

39 -- I want the book! I am crazy of only books `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

156, dice roll.

second guess: 74

Answer (score 2):

73 - Joseph's user number, for lack of any better ideas or a 200-sided dice.

EDIT: second guess:

105 - it somehow stood out to me from the table of still available numbers...

Answer (score 2):

21, of course. I hope I get the book before then, as I won't have much need for LaTeX once the world ends.

Answer (score 2):

123 three digits of consecutive numbers divisible by 3 less than 200.

My second guess is [143](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=143) just because other people will not pick it because of its use as a common code for a corny endearment.

Answer (score 2):

1+1=3 so I'll go with 113. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

66 (just a random number in order to win)

Answer (score 2):

**142**, which is just a number I like.

Answer (score 2):

**17.** Current number of upvotes. Also a number.

Second guess: **56**

Answer (score 2):

12 which is my favourite number also a sacred number.

Answer (score 2):

29 please, although there are already more than enough answers  – as the system is warning me.

Comment: I found that comment quite amusing as well.  I guess artificial intelligence is still a little way off.

Answer (score 2):

I think the number is: 69

;-D

Comment: woohoo!! aw yeaaahhhhhhh

Answer (score 2):

> Dreaming of apples on a wall,
>
> And dreaming often, dear,
>
> I dreamed that, if I counted all
>
> -- How many would appear?

The answer is **10**.

Edit (second guess): 
or maybe **9**?

Answer (score 2):

8, just because it's my birthday.
Second guess: 65.

Answer (score 2):

Others beat me at posting my favorite numbers, so here is my (wild) guess:

**31** (my birthday `:)`)

My second guess, since it's still not taken:

**108**

**EDIT**: *If* I win, I'd like the book to be signed. `:)`

Comment: I feel like congratulating myself on the originality of my choice... `:D`

Answer (score 2):

18 - day of birth - just because 22 was already taken.

Answer (score 2):

138 - Since I'm unable to decide myself such an important thing, I asked http://www.random.org/ and this was the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ummm... 60? 60. Definitely 60! How many characters is that...

Answer (score 2):

199

No witty comment, but I did get this message, as I'm sure lots of other folks did.

[image]

Comment: So did you read through all the existing answers first to make sure that your answer will be contributing something new?

Answer (score 2):

[23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_%28number%29) and 124.

Comment: I can't Fnord believe 23 was still Fnord available...

Answer (score 2):

7

50

Answer (score 2):

98 


& 83

Answer (score 2):

**139**

Because at this time, these numbers were already given:

```
1 2 3 7 8 10 11 12 13 15 17 18 21 22 23 27 28 29 30 31 33 35 39 42 43 49 57 60 61 66 67 69 73 78 84 85 88 91 96 97 100 101 109 111 113 117 118 119 121 123 127 128 131 137 138 142 144 149 154 156 170 172 177 191 199 200 250
```

So, in bash:

```
$ a=( 1 2 3 7 8 10 11 12 13 15 17 18 21 22 23 27 28 29 30 31 33 35 39 42 43 49 57 60 61 66 67 69 73 78 84 85 88 91 96 97 100 101 109 111 113 117 118 119 121 123 127 128 131 137 138 142 144 149 154 156 170 172 177 191 199 200 250 )
$ IFS=+ read s <<< "${a[*]}"
$ echo $((s%200+1))
139
```

Answer (score 2):

47, because according to [The 47 society](http://www.47.net/47society/47story/) *"47 appears to be the quintessential random number of the universe."*

Edit: Second guess: 094

Answer (score 2):

I'm a TeX newbie, but it'd be cool to win a book :)

185.

Should I edit the answer to add my number in, or are the admins taking care of that?

**Edit:**
My second answer: 75.

Comment: I’m going to edit this for you right now.

Answer (score 1):

200 .... and some text for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

149

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

Answer (score 1):

27, because I am 27 years old!

Answer (score 1):

i'll go for: 11

because it's more than 10 and less than twelve and also because you need to type at least 30 characters...

Answer (score 1):

101 is mine, and this is some text to reach 30 chars

Answer (score 1):

**35**.  Because.  (Well, I have a reason to choose this number, which I'll disclose if I win:P.  Not that I believe it has greater chances or anything like that;).)

Answer (score 1):

119 - just a random choice :).

Answer (score 1):

96, please. A nicely balanced yet untraditional number indeed.

Answer (score 1):

15 - a very nice number indeed!

Answer (score 1):

**61**

I used R to draw a random number.

```
> sample.int(200,1)
[1] 61
```

I tossed a die and came up with **6** as my second number.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is 167. This should be > 30 characters for an answer now :)

Answer (score 1):

110

Donald E. Knuth’s birthday in British/American date format: 1/10.

Answer (score 1):

64

The first non-trivial square that is also a cube, of course... does it matter though?

Answer (score 1):

I have no preference for any number, so I'll pick one at random:

```
  $ sudo apt-get install rand   
  $ rand -M 200
  58
```

And yes, it is easier `sample(1:200;1)` in R, but is too sort to avoid

> Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because body must be at least 30 characters.

Well, definitively:  **58**

Answer (score 1):

**19**

The hundredth part of the century I was born. ;-)

<sup>*Edit:* I just notice, this could be *slightly* misleading, but I won’t change it.</sup>

Second number, this time using a random generator:

**164**

Answer (score 1):

**193**

No reason.................

Answer (score 1):

**<>---<> <>---<>     99     <>---<> <>---<>**

Answer (score 1):

My picks (now that I've been allowed a second number):

```
n in (38, 171)
```

Answer (score 1):

16, just because it is 7+9. And now the body is sufficiently long.

Answer (score 1):

150 - half the number of pages the book has.

As a second guess: 116... for no special reason.

Answer (score 1):

9 - My lucky number forever....

Answer (score 1):

102 - Year and month of my daughters birth =)

Answer (score 1):

OK Thanks Marc. This is my second number -- 169

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**80**, as my first number.
**166**, as my second one.

I hope to be lucky!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to choose 14, as it's a [random number](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=66969&p=1%22random%20number%22), and 112.

Answer (score 1):

## 190! I choose you!

Just because.

Answer (score 0):

RE(189 + 190i) For the hell of it.

Answer (score 0):

I select the number **106**.  Why not give it a shot?

Answer (score 0):

81 is the number I pick. I don't like that 30 character limit thing...

And 37 since we can pick a second number!

Answer (score 0):

**24**

It has to be 24 right? What else could it be?

Well, else it could be **54**
(What is nine times six?)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take **197** as my first guess and **135** as the second one.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Second guess, as chosen by `R`, is 135. Already chosen (see comment).</strike>

New, second guess is **160**

Comment: already chosen by me 8 min ago

Comment: Ok, missed that -- I was working from the main list in the question itself which was not up to date. I'll edit and choose another.

Answer (score 0):

More than 30 answers? Then 32 it is.

Answer (score 0):

163

188

Seems easy enough to me (now that I understand what numbers were taken and what ones were not).

Answer (score 0):

187, my second stab with the same motivation: why not? I am desperate.

Answer (score 0):

129 for me, because it's not picked yet.

Answer (score 0):

My second guess is **162**. Maybe this one will win?

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess 34 (TeX's age) and 157.

Answer (score 0):

```
bash$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Jun 20 2012, 16:23:33) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> all = [i+1 for i in range(200)]
>>> chosen = 
[127, 250,  42, 131,  88, 191, 118, 172, 121, 111,  30,  33, 109,  72,   2,  28,
 154,  43,  78,  85, 177, 170,  84, 128,  49, 137,   1,  91,   8,  22,  18,  23,
 117,  36, 144,  55,  97,  13,   3,  39, 156,  21, 123, 113,  66, 100, 142,  17,
  12,  29,  69,  31, 138,  60,   7, 199, 139,  71,  98, 185,  10,   9,  67, 120,
  47,  73, 105, 200, 149,  27,  11, 101,  35, 119,  57,  96,  15, 167, 110,  54,
  58,  19, 193,  99,  16, 150,   9, 102,  38, 171,  61,   6, 169,   4,   5, 189,
 106,  87,  37,  24,  54, 197, 135, 160,  32, 163, 188, 187, 129,  80, 166, 162,
  14,  34, 157,  14, 112]
>>> available = [i for i in all if i not in chosen]                                                                              >>> choices = [random.choice(available) for i in range(2)]                                                                       >>> chosen += choices
>>> print choices
[183, 45]
>>> print chosen
[127, 250,  42, 131,  88, 191, 118, 172, 121, 111,  30,  33, 109,  72,   2,  28,
 154,  43,  78,  85, 177, 170,  84, 128,  49, 137,   1,  91,   8,  22,  18,  23,
 117,  36, 144,  55,  97,  13,   3,  39, 156,  21, 123, 113,  66, 100, 142,  17,
  12,  29,  69,  31, 138,  60,   7, 199, 139,  71,  98, 185,  10,   9,  67, 120,
  47,  73, 105, 200, 149,  27,  11, 101,  35, 119,  57,  96,  15, 167, 110,  54,
  58,  19, 193,  99,  16, 150,   9, 102,  38, 171,  61,   6, 169,   4,   5, 189,
 106,  87,  37,  24,  54, 197, 135, 160,  32, 163, 188, 187, 129,  80, 166, 162,
  14,  34, 157,  14, 112, 183,  45]
>>> available = [i for i in all if i not in chosen]
>>> print available
[20,  25,  26,  40,  41,  44,  46,  48,  50,  51,  52,  53,  56,  59,  62,  63,
 64,  65,  68,  70,  74,  75,  76,  77,  79,  81,  82,  83,  86,  89,  90,  92,
 93,  94,  95, 103, 104, 107, 108, 112, 114, 115, 116, 124, 125, 126, 130, 132,
133, 134, 136, 140, 141, 143, 145, 146, 147, 148, 151, 152, 153, 155, 158, 159,
161, 164, 165, 168, 173, 174, 175, 176, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 184, 186, 190,
192, 194, 195, 196, 198]
>>> exit()
bash$ logout

[Process completed]
```

I suppose that settles it. **183 and 45** for me :D

The list of available numbers as of writing is in this post, but unfortunately I don't have more time to go through and grab all the timestamps :( sorry!

Comment: I tried editing the original post, but there seems to be a conflict in my records and its --- I'm going to leave well enough alone :(

Comment: It seems that this has already gotten somewhat out of hand.  Anyone have a script that can pull the relevant info?

Answer (score 0):

**198**... it has to be 198. :-)

Answer (score 0):

87 - and I'm still convinced my first guess was right ;-)

Answer (score 0):

20

This is for my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

77 and 145.
Like both those numbers :)

Answer (score 0):

133 (it's how wide mainframe listings are) and 51 (it's a good idea in Brazil)

Comment: Why the answers here are getting downvoted is a mystery to me!

Comment: @HarishKumar : somebody hates me

Comment: @HarishKumar: The mystery is revealed. Down voting 133 results in 132. Note: I did not do that.

Comment: @GarbageCollector : Must be an off-by-one error. They should have started counting from 1, not 0

Answer (score 0):

180 is the key... Don't know why, but it is... :)

Answer (score 0):

**25** and **26** are my two guesses.

**EDIT:** Oops, guessed 105 and 106 then realized I had read the thing wrong and they were already taken.

Answer (score 0):

**195** and **196** of course.

Answer (score 0):

I choose **089** :) Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Guess 1: 173
Guess 2: 174

....

Comment: I added your numbers to the lists and plot above.

Answer (score 0):

My second answer but in plain TeX.

```
\def\godnumber{62}
\godnumber
\bye
```

### Analysis

> Because 62 is a positive integer greater than 61 but less than 63.

My first choice is [33 (thirty three)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3015/19356).

Answer (score 0):

My second guess is 125.

Please sign the book :)

Comment: I can only sign it if the winner wants it:-)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen And since I picked the winner number 125, I was telling you I want you to sign it :P

Comment: Now I get got it. I'd have to check the number first. This may take one or two days.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen No problem, I was just being cheeky (but I should have been less subtle). Playing is fun enough, winning the book would "just" be a bonus. Thanks for doing this!

Comment: I was just pretending I didn't understand....

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Oh, so you were the ultimate cheeky! "cheek the cheeker". You got me!

Comment: Sorry about that. It won't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

My second guess: **41**

Because it is [the room number](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)

Answer (score 0):

How about **114** and **92**?

By the way, great lottery!

Answer (score 0):

My second guess is 122 and this is more text.

Answer (score 0):

I take **152** and **153**. 
moretext

Answer (score 0):

52, that's my choice. The other had already been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

Second guess: 126.

Reason: it's the remaining case where the Kevaire invariant problem is still open.

Answer (score 0):

My first choice is number **059**

Answer (score 0):

My secong guess: **165**

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

79 -- because I misinterpreted the list above and my original choice had already been chosen.

Answer (score 0):

### $\{ 176 , 187 \}$

Because they happen to be mupltiples of 11 (I like the ones which are less than 200), and because 176 has the added feature of being a multiple of 16.