# Who wants to win a duck? Wait, what?

Tags: discussion, publicity, ducks

## Introduction

Hello there, fellow TeX.sx users! I'm organizing a lottery. The idea is very similar to [Who Wants to Win a LaTeX Book?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2982), but both the lottery algorithm and the prize are different. Let me explain some things first.

### Who are you?

I'm some random dude on the Internet who happens to hang out a lot in this very community. `:)`

### What is the prize?

The prize will be a lovely duck.

### Wait a minute, did you say *duck*?

Yes! `:)` But not a *real* duck, it will be a hand puppet duck:

[image: Quack]

Lovely, isn't it?

### Why a duck? Why not a lion?

Good question. `:)` I always like to provide examples with ducks when I write answers. To my surprise, the theme got a very positive feedback from the community and it spread to everybody. Of course, a lion would be better, but hey, it's free! And it's a duck! `:)`

### Why a hand puppet?

I have absolutely no idea. But since I got this duck, I thought it would be a good idea to start a contest! `:)`

## Rules

- To win the duck you must guess a number in the range 1-200. The first person who guesses the right number gets the duck.
- Contestants may submit 2 valid guesses.
- Please post your guess as an answer to this meta question, not as a comment.
- Contestants must have been a member of TeX.sx before 21 December, 2013.

## The lottery

I'll use the following code to pick the winner:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_duck_contest_prop
\int_new:N \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int
\bool_new:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
\tl_new:N \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
\int_new:N \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int

\NewDocumentCommand { \person } { m m }
{
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_duck_contest_prop { ##1 }
        {
            Hey! ~ #2 ~ wants ~ to ~ be ~ naughty! ~
            The ~ number ~ ##1 ~ was ~ already ~ chosen! \par
        }
        {
            \prop_gput:Nnn \g_duck_contest_prop { ##1 } { #2 }
            \int_gset:Nn \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int
            {
                \int_max:nn { \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int } { ##1 }
            }
        }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \winner } { }
{
    \bool_do_until:Nn \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
    {
        \pgfmathrandom{1, \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int}
        \prop_get:NoN \g_duck_contest_prop { \pgfmathresult } \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
        \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
        {
            \bool_set_true:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
        }
    }
    \int_set_eq:NN \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int \pgfmathresult
    \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:NnN { No }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \winningnumber } { }
{
    \int_to_arabic:n \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% add yourself here
% ==============================
% For example, in the following line
% I picked 1 and 27, but I'm not
% participating in the contest :)
% \person{1,27}{Paulo Cereda}

\person{137,143}{Marco Daniel}
\person{65,105}{Ethan Bolker}
\person{68,130}{giordano}
\person{123,77}{Werner}
\person{124,100}{Stiff Jokes}
\person{15,97}{David Carlisle}
\person{22,44}{egreg}
\person{42,37}{tohecz}
\person{108,69}{Count Zero}
\person{47,167}{ppr}
\person{26,2}{marczellm}
\person{3,30}{Papiro}
\person{131,144}{percusse}
\person{33,66}{Harish Kumar}
\person{1,200}{Przemysław Scherwentke}
\person{4,5}{Frank Mittelbach}
\person{13,93}{Adam}
\person{23,177}{cgnieder}
\person{11,121}{texenthusiast}
\person{50,52}{Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine}
\person{14,29}{ricmarques}
\person{117,183}{Newb}
\person{82,88}{Francesco Endrici}
\person{122,171}{Claudio Fiandrino}
\person{17,21}{Dror}
\person{153,154}{topskip}
\person{74,147}{Sigur}
\person{193,38}{ComFreek}
\person{113,31}{Wayne Werner}
\person{6,7}{Andrew Stacey}
\person{12,171}{azetina}
\person{8,63}{Ignasi}
\person{28,99}{Andrea L.}
\person{25,116}{Benedikt Bauer}
\person{126,129}{Alan Munn}
\person{99,199}{lvaneesbeeck}
\person{197,53}{Pouya}
\person{20,125}{afrendeiro}
\person{45,152}{kan}
\person{114,115}{Philip}
\person{24,133}{doncherry}
\person{27,35}{Yori}
\person{79,186}{knut}
\person{12,173}{fifaltra}
\person{28,196}{Michael Hoppe}
\person{94,81}{XZS}
\person{10,172}{OSjerick}
\person{56,163}{laxxy}

% there was an entry to the code, but not as
% a proper answer, I'm sorry
% \person{8,9}{Joe Corneli}
% ==============================

% the announcement
The winner is \winner, with \winningnumber! Congratulations!

\end{document}
```

I'll run this code with all the contestants, post a video of it and announce the winner.

## The date

Hopefully, I'll get the code running on January 1st, 2014, and announce the winner. `:)`

Good luck! `:)` And by the way, welcome to TeX.sx, the friendliest and most awesome community in the whole StackExchange network! They give us hats, right? We give ducks!

---

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|009|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|016|◖■◗|018|019|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|032|◖■◗|034|◖■◗|036|◖■◗|◖■◗|039|040|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|041|◖■◗|043|◖■◗|◖■◗|046|◖■◗|048|049|◖■◗|051|◖■◗|◖■◗|054|055|◖■◗|057|058|059|060|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|061|062|◖■◗|064|◖■◗|◖■◗|067|◖■◗|◖■◗|070|071|072|073|◖■◗|075|076|◖■◗|078|◖■◗|080|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|083|084|085|086|087|◖■◗|089|090|091|092|◖■◗|◖■◗|095|096|◖■◗|098|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|101|102|103|104|◖■◗|106|107|◖■◗|109|110|111|112|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|118|119|120|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|127|128|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|132|◖■◗|134|135|136|◖■◗|138|139|140|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|141|142|◖■◗|◖■◗|145|146|◖■◗|148|149|150|151|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|155|156|157|158|159|160|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|161|162|◖■◗|164|165|166|◖■◗|168|169|170|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|174|175|176|◖■◗|178|179|180|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|181|182|◖■◗|184|185|◖■◗|187|188|189|190|191|192|◖■◗|194|195|◖■◗|◖■◗|198|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

◖■◗
```

## Update

[image: Duck winner]

Congrats to **Dror** for picking **17**, the winning number! And thanks to all that joined the contest! Happy New Year! [Here's the video](https://vimeo.com/83109311) with me running the code. `:)`

Comment: Gambling is not good for children.

Comment: @StiffJokes: maybe it teaches a valuable lesson: do not gamble. Not even once. `:)`

Comment: [Nine nine nine nine nine nine.](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: LOL if you check some of the previous reviews of the code, you'll see David's optimization, which employs quite the same implementation of Dilbert's. `:P`

Comment: 4 - the IEEE vetted random number (according to [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/221/)'s hovertext)

Comment: `\begin{equation}\pi\end{equation}`

Comment: 4 numbers per person might be useful to finalize this game much faster.

Comment: Am I supposed to edit the code above so that I'm in it? Because I can't. Does that mean I can't take part in the lottery?

Comment: With no better way to close competitions, 'off-topic' it is: the competition is now closed to new entries, and a winner will be announced (edited in/accepted) soon.

Comment: Interesting things about the video: (1) You failed to highlight your code from top to bottom so you needed to do it from bottom to top. (2) Sadly, even you did not use `arara` to compile the code. :-)

Comment: @JosephWright: How long do we have to wait for closing this question? Or should it be in "on hold" status forever?

Comment: @StiffJokes The 'on hold' business lasts a week: it's there because there was a feeling that 'closed' was too 'final' in general. It's not something that's selectable for individual questions: closing puts them on hold for one week then they show closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Number I: 17
- Number II: 21

Comment: Congrats, you won the duck! `:)`

Comment: <blushes>... :)

Answer (score 10):

I missed the [previous one](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3030/3235) by one. As every broke gambler knows, patience is the archenemy of the odds. So here we go;

---

**131**; I'm a random number generator myself and this is the result.

Also another generator agrees;

[image]

I have generated *a new one*  which is 144.

Comment: Great use of *Rain Man* there.

Answer (score 9):

Number 1: 68

Number 2: 130

Numbers generated using Emacs' `random` function, I'm sure you will appreciate it `:)`  Here is the code

```
(dolist (i '(1 2))
  (insert (concat (number-to-string (1+ (random 199))) " ")))
```

Answer (score 7):

15,97

(97 feels *very* lucky)

Comment: 97 seems to be *too* lucky after your edit `:-/`

Comment: @giordano: I was wondering what the edit was until I ran the code. `:P`

Answer (score 7):

42, 37

Answer (score 6):

Number 1: 137

Number 2: 143

Answer (score 6):

Number 1: 65

Number 2: 105

(65 is the smallest number expressible as the sum of two squares two ways. 105 is the product of the first three odd primes, and what 7 NYC subway tokens cost when I lived there many years ago.)

Answer (score 6):

Number 1: 22

Number 2: 44

Answer (score 6):

My favorite numbers: 108, 69. :)

Answer (score 6):

47, 167 :-)

---

"Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 20." : not too short anymore...

Answer (score 6):

26, 2.

..............................

Answer (score 6):

My luck numbers are 4 and 5 but I need a few more words here to make it stick.

Answer (score 5):

Number 1: 123

Number 2: 77

Answer (score 5):

With PSTricks' tools.

```
\documentclass[preview,border={6pt 6pt 22pt 12pt},varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-tools}

\def\GetRand{\psPrintValue{rand 201 mod}}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}
\GetRand\\\GetRand
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Why can't we give a duck (0) as the answer? ;-)

Number 1: 33

Number 2: 66

Comment: @paulo won't understand the cricket reference:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Hehe. I know. I think only you and me are in this gang. You people taught us the game.

Comment: ooh there's cricket involved?

Comment: I'm trying hard to forget that I ever heard of cricket right now ...

Comment: @PauloCereda In cricket, if a batsman gets out without scoring, we say " he is gone for a *duck*" :-)

Comment: @PauloCereda BTW '0' is India's contribution to the world of mathematics. We say on a lighter note, *India's contribution to mathematics is 0*. ;-)

Comment: @Harish: ooh! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Number 1: 117

Number 2: 183

Thanks for hosting this raffle :-)

Answer (score 5):

99 and 199. Do you really think they're chosen at random?

Answer (score 4):

1 and 200. Should I explain, that they are the ends of the interval? ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Number 1: 13

Number 2: 93

Answer (score 4):

23, 177

Answer (score 4):

My wild guesses

Number 1 : 11

Number 2:  121

Answer (score 4):

```
(50, 52) // chosen by fair d100 roll.
         // guaranteed to be random.
```

Answer (score 4):

1st Number: **29** (current Paulo Cereda's age, according to his profile page)
2nd Number: **14** (because the lottery will happen in 2014).

And yes, I understood that the numbers in the lottery will be randomly picked... but that does **not** mean my guesses have to be random as well! **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

153 and number 154. Both will win!

Answer (score 4):

Number 1:  **74**

Number 2: **147**

No reason to choice them.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Number 1: 193</kbd>
<kbd>Number 2:  38</kbd>

These are parts of [Donald Knuth's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) year of birth: <kbd>1938</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

Number 1: 113

Number 2: 31

Maybe they'll turn out to be lucky for me and I'll get a duck!

Answer (score 4):

6,​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​7

Answer (score 4):

12 and 171. Hopefully I will win a duck for the first time.

Comment: Now that I'm tabulating the answers, I noticed that Claudio already picked 171. Hurry up, I'll wait for you to pick another number. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

Number 1: 8

Number 2: 63

Answer (score 4):

Mmh... I hope that [FakeNameGenerator](http://it.fakenamegenerator.com) will grant me some luck!

Number One:`28`

Number Two:`99`

```
Happy Christmas Eve!
\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

**25**, because it's today's date. And **116** because I need another number!

Answer (score 4):

My numbers:

Number 1: 126

Number 2: 129

Not random, not chosen by Emacs.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Number 1: `1`</strike>

<strike>Number 2: `200`</strike>

<strike>Neither random nor probable.</strike>

### Edit

They were already taken :/

So my new choices:

Number 1: `197`

Number 2: `53`

P.S. Have you noticed how every one is biased toward prime numbers!?

Answer (score 4):

1. 20
2. 125

This is a long answer now :)

Answer (score 4):

- Number 45
- Number 152

I was the winner last time. And, I want ducks too :-)

Answer (score 4):

Juhu! My first answer in the tex community, 114, 115.

Answer (score 4):

Number one: **24**
Number two: **133**

Answer (score 4):

27 and 35 because my current reputation is 2735.

Comment: Darn, my reputation changed. Can I still change my choice of numbers ? :)

Answer (score 3):

Number 1: 82

Number 2: 88

Very nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

Number 1: 122.

Number 2: 171.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to take 3 and 6 (the age of my children who would love the duck).
But the numbers are already away.

So I take:

79 and 186

I used a random function with check for already used numbers.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds fun! I will go for 12 and 173.

Answer (score 3):

Well, my lucky numbers are 28 and 196.

Answer (score 3):

As I mostly deal with `TikZ`, I let `PGF` handle the job for me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\first}{random(1, 200)}
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{random(1, 200)}
  \textbackslash{}person\{\first,\second\}\{xzs\}
\end{document}
```

[image: \person{94,81}{xzs}]

Answer (score 3):

My fantastic lucky numbers are: <kbd>010</kbd> and <kbd>172</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

56, 163. Quack, quack, quack, quack!!