# The duck giveaway 2016

Tags: discussion, fun, publicity, ducks

> Friends, the contest is over! The winning number was **3**, picked by **R. Schumacher**. Thanks everybody for joining the contest!

'ello, ladies and gentlemen, boys and girls, ducks and mallards, children of all ages! It is time for organizing another amazing community lottery, our beloved **duck giveaway 2016**! Quack!

## The prize

The prize will be a lovely duck! Not a real one, I am afraid (note to self: organize another lottery with *real ducks* in the future), it will be a hand puppet duck:

[image: Quack!]

Lovely, isn't it?

## Again, why a duck? Why not a lion?

As I mentioned in the thread linked [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4076), I always like to provide examples with ducks when I write answers. To my surprise, the theme got a very positive feedback from the community and it spread to everybody. Of course, a lion would be better, but hey, it's free! And it's a duck! `:)`

## Why a hand puppet?

This will be our second lottery offering a duck puppet and I still have absolutely no idea. But since I got this duck again, I thought it would be a good idea to start a contest! `:)`

## Rules

Rules from last lottery still apply:

- To win the duck you must guess a number in the range 1-200. The first person who guesses the right number gets the duck.
- Contestants may submit 2 valid guesses.
- Please post your guess as an answer to this meta question, not as a comment.
- Contestants must have been a member of TeX.sx before 1 March, 2016.

Two additional mentions:

- If two or more people choose the same number, only the oldest entry will be considered. The other guesses will be automatically disqualified.
- If you win the contest, I will need your real name and address for shipping and customs purposes (you can contact me through email, so only I will have privileged access). If you seek anonymity, we advise you to not enter this contest.

**Please don't forget to edit the punch card with your numbers.**

---

## The lottery

As seen in the last lottery, I'll use the following code to pick the winner (special thanks to the awesome LaTeX Project for LaTeX3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_duck_contest_prop
\int_new:N \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int
\bool_new:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
\tl_new:N \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
\int_new:N \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int

\NewDocumentCommand { \person } { m m }
{
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_duck_contest_prop { ##1 }
        {
            Hey! ~ #2 ~ wants ~ to ~ be ~ naughty! ~
            The ~ number ~ ##1 ~ was ~ already ~ chosen! \par
        }
        {
            \prop_gput:Nnn \g_duck_contest_prop { ##1 } { #2 }
            \int_gset:Nn \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int
            {
                \int_max:nn { \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int } { ##1 }
            }
        }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \winner } { }
{
    \bool_do_until:Nn \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
    {
        \pgfmathrandom{1, \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int}
        \prop_get:NoN \g_duck_contest_prop { \pgfmathresult } \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
        \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
        {
            \bool_set_true:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
        }
    }
    \int_set_eq:NN \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int \pgfmathresult
    \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:NnN { No }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \winningnumber } { }
{
    \int_to_arabic:n \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% add yourself here
% ==============================
% For example, in the following line
% I picked 1 and 27, but I'm not
% participating in the contest :)
% \person{1,27}{Paulo Cereda}
\person{5,29}{Ulrike Fischer}
\person{42,108}{Christian Hupfer}
\person{0,201}{David Carlisle}
\person{1,200}{egreg}
\person{88,97}{yo'}
\person{6,28}{Matsmath}
\person{17,23}{Martin Schröder}
\person{13,111}{cfr}
\person{50,150}{Werner}
\person{199,91}{Kurt}
\person{133,55}{Arun Debray}
\person{123,132}{A Feldman}
\person{2,198}{Peter Grill}
\person{52,190}{Paul Gaborit}
\person{7,70}{Henri Menke}
\person{8,63}{Ignasi}
\person{84,157}{Sigur}
\person{18,67}{EngBIRD}
\person{131,68}{percusse}
\person{119,120}{Marijn}
\person{101,102}{runartrollet}
\person{80,112}{Alan Munn}
\person{113,86}{barbara beeton}
\person{3,197}{R.\ Schumacher}
\person{16,109}{Przemysław Scherwentke}
\person{64,144}{Mico}
\person{57,167}{ppr}
\person{4,76}{René B.\ Christensen}
\person{161,33}{Rmano}
\person{26}{Davïd} % pick another number
\person{22,171}{Claudio Fiandrino}
\person{9,11}{marczellm}
\person{39,196}{ebo}
\person{19,99}{Alenanno}
\person{187,115}{JP-Ellis}
\person{125,147}{silvascientist}
\person{128,32}{Mathias711}
\person{191,192}{azetina}
\person{41,43}{jknappen}
%\person{31,62}{Emre} % user does not meet criteria
\person{122,175}{mvkorpel}
\person{48,53}{martin}
%\person{53,187}{Penbeuz} % both numbers were taken
\person{69,96}{Saravana Kumar}
\person{38,77}{daleif}
\person{142,184}{Romain Picot}
\person{10,100}{Kevin}
\person{179,40}{carnendil}
\person{21,12}{Jon Mark Perry}
\person{92,90}{Canageek}
\person{93,105}{Ethan Bolker}
\person{167,103}{Saz} % 167 was taken
\person{20,46}{Vadim}
\person{83,98}{MattAllegro}
\person{165,166}{Douba}
\person{31,118}{ArTourter}
\person{121,141}{Azor-Ahai}
\person{74,193}{Diaa Abidou}
\person{51,127}{rekire}
\person{24,89}{Thoge}
\person{135,155}{jat255}
\person{61,172}{Kevin}
\person{37,73}{John}
\person{65,47}{Matthew Leingang}
\person{178,15}{Fran}
\person{54,154}{Calvin Khor}
\person{49,81}{Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine}
\person{168,169}{Oxinabox}
\person{164,45}{Habi}
\person{14,25}{Jake}
%\person{2,25}{Xylius} % user does not meet criteria
\person{136,58}{jaam}
\person{85,100}{SHY.John} % 100 was taken
\person{36,153}{wipet}
\person{137,170}{Earthliŋ}
\person{27,71}{FvD}
\person{129,134}{Andreï Kostyrka}
\person{82,195}{Kumaresh}
\person{35,78}{Akiiino}
\person{186,177}{Mostly Harmless}
\person{181,182}{biozic}
\person{126}{Shane} % pick another number
\person{72,79}{Alvaro Carril}
\person{173,107}{TobiO}
%\person{106,107}{pfuhlert} % user does not meet criteria
\person{30,34}{Kurt Pfeifle}
\person{87,116}{Jason Zentz}
\person{114,56}{Brydon Gibson}
%\person{17,89}{René G} % both taken
\person{163,145}{Eridan}
\person{66,110}{JCSalomon}
% ==============================

% the announcement
The winner is \winner, with \winningnumber! Congratulations!

\end{document}
```

I will run this code with all the contestants, post a video of it and announce the winner. The "accepted answer" in this thread will reflect the winning number.

## The date

Hopefully, I will get the code running on July 1, 2016 (Friday), and announce the winner. There will be enough time for guessing the numbers!

Good luck! And by the way, welcome to TeX.sx, the friendliest and most awesome community in the whole StackExchange network! They give us hats, right? We give ducks! Quack! `:)`

---

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|044|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|058|059|060|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|062|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|075|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|094|095|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|104|◖■◗|106|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|117|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|124|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|130|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|138|139|140|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|143|◖■◗|◖■◗|146|◖■◗|148|149|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|156|◖■◗|158|159|160|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|162|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|174|◖■◗|176|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|180|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|◖■◗|◖■◗|183|◖■◗|185|◖■◗|◖■◗|188|189|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|194|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

◖■◗
```

## Results

The winner of the duck in this edition is **R. Schumacher**, and the chosen number was **3**! I recorded the results in my terminal and the [session is available here](https://asciinema.org/a/enctln9bodyao7og6jprqii1b). Thanks everybody for joining the contest! And thanks for being part of this amazing community! Quack! `:)`

Comment: Me wants duck! ;-)

Comment: Mae angen hwyaden arna fi ... ;)

Comment: :'( I have been member only since April, 2016 :'( I'll have to wait till the real duck lottery :'(

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Oh I am so sorry to hear. But there will be other contests in which you can participate. The most important thing is that you are now part of the community. Welcome!

Comment: Thank you, @PauloCereda!

Comment: It's not letting me edit the punch card!

Comment: @silvascientist: we will update accordingly at some point, do not worry. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: The downvote shows a bad attitude really -- (what I've read by some questions/posts here), there's not much of well-designed humorous games/contests on other SE sites. We should be glad to have this one here!

Comment: I've already got one, so I won't enter, but I can confirm it's a cute duck hand puppet :-)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot You don't think it is lonesome for its own kind, then?

Comment: @cfr It sometimes hangs out with a parrot hand puppet for a bit of company. :-)

Comment: I'd be quacking to this if i could :-)

Comment: The {ducks} tag has only 2 questions and 0 followers. This is a sorry state of affairs indeed.

Comment: You should organise a lottery with a prize bobcat delivered via postal service (hello xkcd).

Comment: @onewhaleid: check the tag description. `:)`

Comment: I don't seem to be qualified to participate (because I can't edit this). If I *were* qualified, my pick would be 30 and 34. Also if I did win the duck, I'd give it to the person answering [my question here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315531/8747): *"How to get a 'thousands' separator in `spreadtab` (wrapping `longtable`)?"*

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: You are qualified to enter the contest!

Comment: ...Oh, and Alvaro Carril's line is mis-formatted, using `\person{72,79}(...` insted of `\person{72,79}{...`.

Comment: Has anyone picked numbers by running the actual code with dummy `\person`s inserted?

Comment: Ralph S. won!? Ow, congs to him. The number was 3 or 6? lol

Comment: @Sigur: I see what you did there. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, *there* you mean *on your post*? But you did right, only number bold!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing better than good prime duck, so 3 and 197 (lowest and highest available prime numbers)

Comment: I wonder if the solution to the Riemann hypothesis involves ducks. `:)` Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: @PauloCereda Very Possible.  Here is a reference. Student Handbook for Discrete Mathematics with Ducks : SRRSLEH
by Sarah-Marie Belcastro, CRC Press

Comment: Congrats, you won the duck! `:)`

Answer (score 27):

0, 201
.....................................................

Comment: I will change the range just so you can win the duck. `:)`

Answer (score 20):

2 and 198 (to be close to both egreg and David because they seem to always know what they are doing on TeX.SE)

Comment: That's a good strategy, Peter! `:)` Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: You're starting from a false premise. I'm referring to David, of course.

Answer (score 18):

113 and 86 (the ages of my mother and sister if they had survived this long).

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest, barbara!

Answer (score 17):

1 and 200 (just to be more daring than David)

Comment: ooh this is a cunning plan! Thank you for joining the contest, pal!

Comment: @PauloCereda or is a copied Idea from Mr. Gauss ... You know the story that the teacher asked the class to add the first 100 numbers? Gauss found a simple, very fast solution, easiliy expandable to 1..200, etc.  :-)  (Sorry, could not resist, egreg and Paulo)

Answer (score 12):

133 and 55.

…do stressed ducks quack under pressure when their goose is cooked? (Sorry if you're not pond of these daffy puns.)

Comment: Q: Why do ducks watch the news? A: For the feather forecast! `:)` Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: I watched the feather forecast, but I felt down afterwards...

Comment: @ArunDebray Mine got blown away :-(

Answer (score 10):

[97](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/97_%28number%29) and [88](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/88_%28number%29), because:

```
sage: randint(1,200)
97
sage: randint(1,200)
88
```

Comment: Good luck, Tom! Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 10):

18 and 67 for the years of Canadian confederation.  While not ducks, the Canadian goose is considered waterfowl...

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 9):

I am opting for the two [perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)s [6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6_%28number%29) and [28](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/28_%28number%29).

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 9):

**007** and **070**.  Help me win this, James Bond!

[image]

Comment: Yay, MI5! Thank you for joining the contest, Henri!

Answer (score 9):

As always;

---

**131**; I'm a random number generator myself and this is the result.

Also another generator agrees;

[image]

I have generated another one which is 68.

Comment: I wub you sir! Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: @percusse Wow, not "pseudo" random? I'm impressed

Comment: @Mageek That's how I roll.

Answer (score 8):

13 and 111.

Cwac, cwac a chwac!!

Comment: Pob lwc! Cwac, cwac! `:)`

Answer (score 8):

Well, obviously the numbers have to be generated from "DUCK" and "QUACK", so my choices are 004 and 076.

Generated by concatenating the binary ASCII-representations of each letter, taking the remainder modulo 200 of the resulting binary number, and finally adding 1 to ensure that the result is in the desired range.

Comment: ooh I like this answer! Thank you for joining the contest! `:)`

Answer (score 8):

026 + {197}<sup>†</sup> are the lowest/highest available numbers which total to my rep. Most other users here would have to add a "k" after it! Is there a consolation prize for "lowest rep user to participate"? :)  (The {197}<sup>†</sup> also gets me close to the Big Hitters.)

<sup>† Alas! 197 was already taken, so I will just submit a single entry -- which is allowed by The Rules, and fitting for one such as I! :)</sup>

Comment: Yay, thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: Hey @PauloCereda - If I quack nicely, would you "punch the card" for me? I can't... :/

Comment: was just checking the card, and 197 was already taken by R. Schumacher.  please choose another.  (196 is also chosen, by ebo, but not yet marked, although i'm working through that;)

Comment: @barbarabeeton - And I thought I had checked so closely! (Pretty sure 196 was still available when I entered -- ah well!) Someone *later* also opted for 26, though ... but I think I got in first with that one!

Comment: well, i got bored with what i was doing (or rather, wanted to escape from the headache it was causing), so i checked the marks on the card against the chosen numbers and punched a lot of "holes".  i found quite a few more already-taken numbers, and even one that seems to have been punched with no one having chosen it.  have to be nice to paulo; he's supposed to be writing his thesis.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Not really [structured procrastination](https://web.archive.org/web/20160312140700/http://www.structuredprocrastination.com/) (looks like page is down at native URL) -- but something a bit like it. :) I've been wondering if this Giveaway is, in fact, research and data-gathering for the aforementioned thesis....

Comment: oh, i'm quite a practiced procrastinator.  have got *years* of experience!  deadlines do usually get sufficient attention though, at least enough to deliver what is expected.  the essay you point to is quite delightful, although i'll have to put off reading it till later.

Answer (score 6):

29 and 5 and some text to fill up to fill up to fill up

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest, Ulrike!

Answer (score 6):

I am opting for the number `42` (not because of Douglas Adams, but because that's my current age) and `108` (No, that's not my real age ;-))

But I don't want to win this duck -- it's scratched :-P

Comment: This duck is not pining, he is passed on! This duck is no more! He has ceased to be! He's expired and gone to meet his maker! He's a stiff! Bereft of life, he rests in peace! If you hadn't chose these two numbers he'd be pushing up the daisies! His metabolic processes are now part of a documentary in the History Channel! He's off the twig! He's kicked the bucket, he's shuffled off his mortal coil, run down the curtain and joined the bleeding choir invisible! THIS IS AN EX-DUCK!! Also, thank you for joining the contest! `:)`

Comment: what a pity - I would have chosen 42 too, because it's _the answer_ . Good luck!

Comment: @MostlyHarmless ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 6):

123 and 132 are my picks.  Mostly because I really want that duck! Next year maybe ... duck dinner?

Comment: Good luck, buddy! Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 6):

[image: Am I adding something you?]

A provocative question. But, indeed, I am adding something new -- so far nobody has selected the *correct* answer, which is, of course, **126**. Why is it correct? Because I selected it. Anybody who selected two numbers is simply admitting that they fear that their first choice may be incorrect. Not I. As David has already done, I refuse to take a second number. In the Trumpian future, it is better to be sure you're right and wrong than to be an uncertainty-admitting coward. Only David and I will prosper. To whoever wins this duck, enjoy your duck. For now. Soon David and I will own all ducks, everywhere. And most geese. Then we'll see who's honking...

Comment: Oh my! `:)` Thanks for joining the contest, good luck! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Thank you for organizing! :P

Answer (score 5):

[17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/17_%28number%29), [23 Skidoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/23_enigma).

Comment: ooh spooky! `:)` Thank you for joining the contest, Martin!

Answer (score 5):

50 and 150 are how much I value yellow ducks.

Comment: Yes, yes, YES! Yellow ducks FTW! Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 5):

I choose `199` and `91` because they both build my last reached palindrome rep `19991`.

Comment: ooh palindromic reputation! `:)` Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 5):

008 and 063 and some more characters to pass the minimum required

Update: 037 third number

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest! Muchas gracias, amigo!

Comment: Ignasi, I think you have updated the wrong post see [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6914/101651)

Comment: Oopsie. `:)` `<3`

Comment: @CarLaTeX: I think he wants the duck so much. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda (Almost) everybody wants the duck!

Comment: @PauloCereda: Ups! I did it from my phone and didn't check it. Next time I'll do from a computed with a large display ;-)

Answer (score 5):

I choose `084` and `157` but I don't know why.

Regards.

Comment: Good luck, buddy! Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 5):

64 and 144 -- two square numbers!

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest, Mico! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

57 and 167 for me !

This giveaway should be sponsorised by [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/) (the search engine)

Comment: ooh the more ducks, the quackier! Thank you for joining the contest! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

Well, to honor my *other* "creative" group (photography), I chose 161 and 33...

Hint for 161: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146583/38080

...and 33 is quite trivial.

Comment: Grazie mille for joining the contest!

Comment: Non c'è di che --- thanks for the contest!

Answer (score 4):

80 and 112.

The reason involves character conversion and <del>multiple</del> another language<del>s</del>.

(Guesses as to the exact method solicited in the comments.)

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest, Alan! And I have no idea about the methods. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Really? This is tailor made for your skill set.

Answer (score 4):

125 and 147, because Mathematica's `RandomInteger[{1, 200}, 2]` has decreed it so.

Comment: Thank you very much for joining the contest!

Answer (score 4):

191 and 192 it is, I think :).........

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: oh, dear!  both already chosen!  (007 by Henri Menke, and 111 by cfr.)  please choose again!

Comment: @barbarabeeton changed to 191 and 192

Answer (score 4):

24 and 89

%ToDo think of a witty joke to insert in your answer

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 4):

**129** and **134**.

Just for fun: I did some research and found out that if two numbers are distributed evenly on [0;1], the expected value of their absolute difference should be 1/3 (e.g. not too far apart). Of course no prior research can leverage guessing a random number... But I love birds so much! Keeping decorative chickens and quails at many points in time, and also consuming foie gras with great pleasure! Does everyone remember the hunter (played by Graham Chapman) in Monty Python’s flying circus? “I love animals. That’s why I kill ’em!” So any kind of duck will do: a puppet, a live animal or a nice package of sliced duck breast... Yummi!

[image: Rick Dees and his Disco Duck]

Last but not least... Rick Dees and his Disco Duck (A.K.A. if only wearing those bell-bottom jeans in 2016 paid off for me!).

Comment: Oh my, another MP fan! `:)` Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

119 and 120, because they are neighbors!

Comment: ooh neighbours! Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

`101`,`102`
`\person{101,102}{Runar Kristoffersen}`

Awesome duck!

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest! Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

16 and 109 (the present year and my reputation modulo 200, corrected from 108 as in comments).

Duck, duck. Quack, quack!

Comment: Quack! Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: @PauloCereda :-). And, because Alan Munn observed that 108 is already  taken, may I change it to a first free number above it? I would simply write that it is 109, but `1st free above 108` is a safer formulation.

Comment: ooh safer formulations `:)`

Answer (score 3):

As in the previous context was already taken, I'll go for `022` this time. Second: `171`

Comment: Grazie mille, Claudio!

Answer (score 3):

Since `duck` shall be the answer, and since even random seems to be duck-dependant in this case, I choose:

- **`39`** because `DUCK = 4+21+3+11`
- **`196`** because `DUCK = 4*21*3*11 = 2772` and `2*7*7*2=196`

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: And `1*9*6 = 54` and `5*4 = 20` and `2*0 = 0`.

Answer (score 3):

41 and 43 for they are the smallest available twin primes.

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

Others have used random number generators to come up with their guesses. But ultimately, random number generators still depend on physical processes. They have stochasticism, but I can do better. By selecting numbers myself, using my own imagination and creativity to do so, I am tapping into something that is neither deterministic nor random, but something yet more unpredictable - the free will of the human spirit! Controllable, yet not controlled by the rules of nature!

Um, I'll go with 10 and 100. That sounds good.

Comment: (I know that 1 and 2 were already selected. I'm not a very active member on this site, so I think a more veteran user deserves the prize. I just thought it would be fun to join in with a silly post :D)

Comment: Hi Kevin! C'mon buddy, pick two valid numbers! Everyone in this community is important! Think of the possibility of winning a duck! Please, reconsider. `:)`

Comment: If you insist :) I'll go with 10 and 100, two suitably uninspired numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

<del>1 (bronze badge)</del> and 179 (my reputation). That's me today.

1 is taken, but I think 40 (my age) is available.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

93 (because 91 - the only number less than 100 that looks like a prime but isn't - is taken)

105 (because it's 3*5*7 and what 7 subway tokens cost in NY years ago)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

Let's take 20 and 46 since they are the only left numbers in the duck-duck-goose game sequence http://oeis.org/A182459 :)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

I let the great o**R**acle to speak for me:

```
> sample(1:200,2)
[1] 178  15
```

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 3):

54 and 154? has a non-mathematical ring to it.

Comment: I can't edit the punchcard :(

Comment: Hi, thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: Thanks @PauloCereda ! :)

Answer (score 3):

14 and 25, because those are the lowest numbers that are still available.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, Jake!

Comment: @PauloCereda: Thanks for organising it!

Answer (score 3):

82 (year of birth)

195 (height in centimetre)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

My choice: 052, 190 ............

Comment: @PauloCereda I changed my choices...

Answer (score 2):

009 and 011.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwSWEJmQgkE

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: @PauloCereda 11 then.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'll choose

019 and 099

because they are my fave numbers. :D

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, buddy!

Comment: @PauloCereda Always a pleasure :D

Answer (score 2):

Umm umm umm ... 
I'm thinking.. Umm.. 167 and 103

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: oops!  167 already chosen by ppr.  please try again.

Comment: As barbara mentioned, 167 is already chosen. Could you please pick another number? `:)`

Answer (score 2):

83 and 98...years of birth of me and my brother :)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

165, 166. Because.
An answer is an answer is an answer.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

I'll go for 031 and 118. not the same method to get these numbers but couldn't get two available numbers using the same so here you go!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It seems Emre already chose 31. Could you pick another number? `:)`

Comment: ok although the comments on the answer seem to suggest that it would not be considered due to the account be too recent.

Comment: Oh indeed. Sticky situation. I was just collecting answers, deeply sorry.

Comment: No worries Paulo

Answer (score 2):

121 and 141 because I like palindromes and there's something nice about an even number being flanked by odd numbers.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

I guess 74 and 193

Good duck ;)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: Many thanks, I didn't notice before.

Answer (score 2):

I take `051` because my current IP ends with that number and `127` because it is 0x1111111. `:)`

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: @PauloCereda would you be so kind to delete my numbers from the question? I have too less reputation to do that.

Comment: Done, punchcard edited. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

`135` and `155`, please! (30char)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

61 and 172 -- just two random numbers :)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: Thanks for hosting!

Answer (score 2):

I choose my lucky number 37 and its reverse 73. Oh how I want that duck!

Comment: Wishing you luck! `:)` Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

I'll take the first two numbers given by random.org that weren't taken: 65 and 47.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

I will take in 168, 169
Thankyou

Could someone with >2K rep punch for me?

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

164 and 45, as suggested by random.org

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

35 and 78. I got these numbers by asking strangers on the street, so they must be random =)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

`181`, because it's yet another palindrome, and `182`, because it sits next to a palindrome. I don't particularly like those numbers, but wait and see...

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

72 and 79 are luckily still available! They're my grandparent's ages and just this saturday I tried to explain to them what LaTeX is (using [Paulo's wonderful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94910/45978)).

Answer (score 2):

`087` and `116` — based loosely on my birth year and the year I finished my PhD.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 2):

66 & 110, because I noticed those unclaimed numbers before others.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle of Mathematica has foretold that the numbers will be either `187` or `115` :)

Comment: Thank you very much for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

128 and 32! That were the first two integers that were both free, and were foretold by Python's numpy!

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

My choice: 31 and 62. I hope this is not too late.

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: Emre, we are in a quite sensitive situation: your profile says you are a registered member of TeX.sx since March 9, and the rules for this specific contest say participants should be registered at least in March 1. I am so sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but I am afraid your entry will not be considered. But you will surely be qualified for the next contest happening in the second semester. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

My choices are 122 and 175, chosen by random.

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

My choices: 48 and 53 because the sum is my reputation at writing (and they're not yet taken).

Comment: And obviously, I can't edit the punchcard yet.

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest! We will edit the punchcard at some point. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

151 152 because my favorite numbers were taken

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Comment: both already chosen (53 by martin, and 187 by JP-Ellis).  please try again.

Comment: As barbara mentioned, both numbers were already taken. Could you please choose two other numbers? `:)`

Answer (score 1):

69 and 96 ;) (Body must be at least 30 characters; I have entered whaaaat?)

Comment: Thank you for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

38 and 77, and because the system wants me to here are some filler text ;-)

Comment: Yay, thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

`142` and `184`. Why? Because "Coin Coin !" `:-)`

Comment: Coin coin! `:)`

Comment: Quack quack ! `:-)`

Answer (score 1):

okay second time lucky; 21,12 because of the album by Rush

Comment: Thank you very much for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with 92, the number of protons in Uranium, and 23, the holy number of Discordia (Because 2+3=5).

Edit: 23 is taken. I'll replace it with 90, the atomic number of Thorium.

Comment: Thank you very much for joining the contest!

Comment: or, (pace tom lehrer) thulium or thallium (but i don't know their atomic numbers).

Answer (score 1):

I’ll guess 49 and 81 — two nice squares.

(And can someone with >2k rep punch the card for me, please?)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

58, 136 (because I can) xxxxxx

Comment: sorry, 131 has already been chosen by percusse.  please try again.

Comment: 058. hope it counts when said here

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest! I edited the question to include 058. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

`85`: My birthday

`100`: The marks I really want in exams (and 100% always not)

Comment: Kevin has already chosen 100.  sorry, not here either.

Comment: Thank you, I am so sad.

=(

Comment: but you can choose another.  look at the "punched card" at the bottom of the question to see what hasn't been chosen yet.

Comment: Will see, studying hard for exams (and using LaTeX for notetaking as well). `=( \;\rightarrow\; =)`

Answer (score 1):

I choose 36 and 153. (dummy text: Body must be at least 30 characters)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, Petr! `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Ducks are my favourite animal.

My guesses are 137 and 170.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: Thank you for organizing it!

Answer (score 1):

I'll take 27 (for ASCII ESC - pressed on VIM many many times while editing LaTeX) and 71 (for ASCII G - as in Great contest!).

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

I took `177` and `186` because

- `42`, which I obviously would have taken because it is the *Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything*, was already taken by someone else unfortunately [for much less obvious reasons](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6654/4009)
- and because they have some partly correlations with some important figures in my life
- and because I want to win the duck.
  :-)

Comment: Yay, thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

*Updating from another answer:*

173 and 107 as new try

Comment: Thank you, both entries are valid! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

My pick is 30 and 34. *(But unfortunately I cannot edit the LaTeX file and add my `\person{30,34}{Kurt Pfeifle}` line, because the edit link is grayed out for me.)*

If I win, I'll give the duck to whoever answers my recent question [*"How to get a 'thousands' separator in `spreadtab` (wrapping `longtable`)?"*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315531/8747),

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest! `:)` To be honest, I don't feel much comfortable of the idea of someone giving the duck away like this. I'd rather prefer if you keep the duck, if you win. I am sure your question will be well answered soon. Cheers! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: It seems the duck is such a high-valued, precious treasure to own -- so this should be an appropriate price to pay for a high-valued answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

114 and 56. Gonna be friends with my 'talk to the duck' ducks at my desk!

Also I'm not allowed to edit the punchcard

Comment: Hello, thanks for joining the contest!

Answer (score 1):

17, 89.......................................................

Comment: sadly, both numbers have already been chosen: 17 by Martin Schröder, and 89 by Thoge.  please try again, first checking the "punch card" at the end of the question to see what's still available,

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of [Ramanjan's Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number), `e^(pi*sqrt(163))`, so I will submit the number `163`.

My choice of `145` has a bit more background to it. In math competitions I participate in, a perfect score is a `150`, and one wrong is `145`. I know that exactly one of my answers to this question will be wrong, so I am submitting the score I would get if this were a math competition and I got one question wrong.

TL;DR `145` and `163` :P

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!