# The duck giveaway 2016, seasonal edition

Tags: discussion, community, fun, publicity

## The Duck Giveaway 2016, Seasonal Edition

> Friends, the contest is over! The winning number was **50**, picked by **CarLaTeX**. Thanks everybody for joining the contest!

'ello, ladies and gentlemen, boys and girls, ducks and mallards, children of all ages! It is time for organizing another amazing community lottery, our beloved **duck giveaway 2016, seasonal edition**! [The previous giveaway](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6652) was a huge success, so let us try that again! Quack!

## The prize

The prize will be a lovely duck! Not a real one, I am afraid (note to self: organize another lottery with *real ducks* in the future), it will be a hand puppet duck:

[image: Quack!]

Lovely, isn't it?

## Again, why a duck? Why not a lion?

As I mentioned in the thread linked [here](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4076), I always like to provide examples with ducks when I write answers. To my surprise, the theme got a very positive feedback from the community and it spread to everybody. Of course, a lion would be better, but hey, it's free! And it's a duck! `:)`

## Why a hand puppet?

This will be our third lottery offering a duck puppet and I still have absolutely no idea. But since I got this duck again, I thought it would be a good idea to start a contest! `:)`

## Rules

Rules from last lottery still apply:

- To win the duck you must guess a number in the range 1-200. The first person who guesses the right number gets the duck.
- Contestants may submit 2 valid guesses. **UPDATE:** Let us spice things up! you can now select a *third* entry! `:)`
- Please post your guess as an answer to this meta question, not as a comment.
- Contestants must have been a member of TeX.sx before 1 November, 2016.

Two additional mentions:

- If two or more people choose the same number, only the oldest entry will be considered. The other guesses will be automatically disqualified.
- If you win the contest, I will need your real name and address for shipping and customs purposes (you can contact me through email, so only I will have privileged access). If you seek anonymity, we advise you to not enter this contest.

**Please don't forget to edit the punch card with your numbers.**

---

## The lottery

As seen in the last lottery, I'll use the following code to pick the winner (special thanks to the awesome LaTeX Project for LaTeX3):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \g_duck_contest_prop
\int_new:N \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int
\bool_new:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
\tl_new:N \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
\int_new:N \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int

\NewDocumentCommand { \person } { m m }
{
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
    {
        \prop_if_in:NnTF \g_duck_contest_prop { ##1 }
        {
            Hey! ~ #2 ~ wants ~ to ~ be ~ naughty! ~
            The ~ number ~ ##1 ~ was ~ already ~ chosen! \par
        }
        {
            \prop_gput:Nnn \g_duck_contest_prop { ##1 } { #2 }
            \int_gset:Nn \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int
            {
                \int_max:nn { \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int } { ##1 }
            }
        }
    }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{ \winner } { }
{
    \bool_do_until:Nn \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
    {
        \pgfmathrandom{1, \g_duck_contest_upper_limit_int}
        \prop_get:NoN \g_duck_contest_prop { \pgfmathresult } \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
        \quark_if_no_value:NF \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
        {
            \bool_set_true:N \l_duck_contest_winner_bool
        }
    }
    \int_set_eq:NN \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int \pgfmathresult
    \l_duck_contest_winner_tl
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_get:NnN { No }

\NewDocumentCommand{ \winningnumber } { }
{
    \int_to_arabic:n \l_duck_contest_winning_number_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% add yourself here
% ==============================
% For example, in the following line
% I picked 1 and 27, but I'm not
% participating in the contest :)
% \person{1,27}{Paulo Cereda}
% ==============================

% the announcement
The winner is \winner, with \winningnumber! Congratulations!

\end{document}
```

I will run this code with all the contestants, post a video of it and announce the winner. The "accepted answer" in this thread will reflect the winning number.

## The date

Hopefully, I will get the code running on December 30, 2016 (Friday), and announce the winner. There will be enough time for guessing the numbers!

Good luck! And by the way, welcome to TeX.sx, the friendliest and most awesome community in the whole StackExchange network! They give us hats, right? We give ducks! Quack! `:)`

---

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|037|038|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|053|●●●|055|056|057|058|059|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|065|●●●|067|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|075|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|091|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|104|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|118|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|122|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|134|135|●●●|●●●|138|139|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|145|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|150|●●●|152|●●●|154|●●●|156|157|158|●●●|160|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|●●●|163|●●●|165|●●●|167|168|●●●|170|●●●|172|●●●|●●●|175|176|●●●|●●●|179|180|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|●●●|182|183|●●●|185|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|●●●|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> **Disclaimer:** Friends, we are now accepting a third entry. I will check the winning number on the answers list, based on the posted date. Note that the edit history will also be considered.

### Results

The winner of the duck in this edition is CarLaTeX, and the chosen number was 50! I recorded the results in my terminal and the session is [available here](https://asciinema.org/a/8pbxouyt2h2k4m5muuzu0m8br). Thanks everybody for joining the contest! And thanks for being part of this amazing community! Quack! `:)`

Comment: Aside: We are working on a proper random number function for `expl3`. Bruno's hopefully going to add something soon (and I'm going to bother the XeTeX people for a couple of primitives)

Comment: @JosephWright: oooooh awesome! So ducks do really help LaTeX3 development! `:)`

Comment: Gwych! Bendigedig! Hwyaden!

Comment: @cfr: I was reflecting that perhaps we need a `mathduck` package even more than a `mathwitch` package… ;-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti But witches have cats! Ducks are great, but I'm not sure about putting one on the back of my broomstick ... But it is like trying to choose between cake and biscuits. Can't we have both?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This time I can participate! Hurrah!

I choose:

`10` my favorite number and even the base of any number system

`50` something that you should never ask a lady.

My third choice is:

`100` thank you Paulo!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thank you @percusse!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, buddy!

Comment: Yay, a third choice! `:)`

Comment: Congrats, you won the duck! `:)`

Answer (score 19):

According to my random number generator I choose **9** and **99**

[image]

http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, pal!

Comment: +1 for the comics

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Done!

Answer (score 15):

12 (For the number of wing feather tips on the last contest duck)

5 (For the number of top knot feather tips on the last contest duck)

[image]

p.s. He says you have to rerun the winner selection if these are chosen. (Duckie says "he is unique, and wants to remain unique!!)

Comment: 12 and 5 punched

Comment: Awwww thanks for posting the duck! `:)` Good luck!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 9):

apparently 0 and 201 I used last time broke the rules, so this time I choose:

**0** and **0**

**Update** Third choice now allowed, I choose **0**

Comment: Oh my, if you win, that means I have to give you two ducks?!

Comment: @PauloCereda According to the rules (or their natural extension), only the oldest 0 counts. We don't know which one is stored first (which is implementation dependent), but fortunately the winner is the same in both cases. So only one duck, no extra budget required.

Answer (score 8):

[image: cathod]

024 *cat*

054 *cathod*

[*cath* is already taken :(]

Caveat: I may have counted incorrectly ....

## EDIT

Plus 161

[image: TSPCD]

Code for pictures is around and about. All ducks courtesy Paulo.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos I already did that, didn't I?

Comment: @PauloCereda ^^ I didn't realise people were posting pics ... ;) Best make up for lost time with two cats and three ducks, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: @cfr you did, but it wasn't flagged at the comments like the others, so I flagged it! ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Ah, I see. Thanks.

Comment: I choose 31 and 194: the first and the last free in this moment.

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke You have to post it as an answer - not a comment.

Comment: @cfr Thank you! Corrected.

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Great Quack! 161 ... punched ...

Answer (score 7):

I choose 101 and 191, the smallest and largest palindromes among the choices.  okay, third number: 076.

Comment: choices 101 and 191 punched.

Comment: Well if you consider that these numbers always have 3 digits, the smallest palindrome would be 010 I guess. And 1 if you drop the leading 0s.

Comment: @Cimbali -- duh ... of course you're correct.  (yesterday was a very long day ...)  but 010 (and 050) were already taken.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, barbara!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: Third number updated!

Answer (score 7):

This contest is awesome.

137 because, if I won, the fine-structure constant (or, in this case, its inverse) would finally have a proper use.

28 because 10^28 is roughly the number of atoms in a duck.

135 because 1.35 is the refractive index of blood plasma across most of the visible range of the electromagnetic spectrum ([reference](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0031-8949/91/1/015503/meta)).

Comment: ooh atomic ducks! Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Cheers, guys! :)

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my post with my third number. I resent 136 and 137 already being chosen, but 135 will have to do. :)

Answer (score 6):

As always;

---

**131**; I'm a random number generator myself and this is the result.

Also another generator agrees;

[image]

I have generated another one which is 68.

Comment: Thanks sir! `:)`

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

`147` (Herz und Mund und Tat und Leben)

`125` (no need to explain what opus number this refers to)

---

Third choice:

`97` (currently listening to KV 297), so modulo 200.

Comment: Grazie mille for joining the contest, pal! `:)`

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

`42` for obvious reasons

and

`3`

edit: I pick `180`

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

30 and 155
stumbled over this while reading about some TeX oddities

Addendum: 179

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 5):

`4` randomly generated by a fair roll of dice :)

`196` because 200 - 4 = 196

`34` as third choice. Thanks to @Paulo Cereda for the extra chance! ;)

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: numbers punched, thanks again ;)

Answer (score 5):

`128`, because the Dreamcast had quite a few Donald Duck games.

`52`, because it's `42` in octal and, you know.

EDIT: And 169 because it is a nice number.

Comment: Numbers punched.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: @PauloCereda why, thank *you*

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda ah nice. Picked and edited and punched. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Yipee! I'd go for `13` and `17`, as well as `123`!
Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: @percusse thank you for having done it for me: I didn't noticed I had sufficient rights to edit the post. my bad.

Comment: no worries.. :) just housekeeping

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda done! thank *you*

Answer (score 3):

I'll go for 86 and 92.

Update: third choice is 96 (punched)!

---

Which are the median and rounded average of all prime numbers between 0 and 200, respectively. All this calculations should give me some luck... `:D`

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest, pal! `:)`

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I'll take the numbers  119 and 199

---

Update: third number: 132

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest! `:)`

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda updated

Comment: Third number updated!

Answer (score 3):

I will go for 22 and 87 and some more words ...

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I saw it, but I choose the numbers for a specific reason and there is no fitting additional number.

Answer (score 3):

I'll select two not so random numbers: 8 and 63.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

069 and 151. Nice visualisation of punched numbers.

**My third choice is 134**

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I will go for 23 and 124 and some lore ipsum...

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I choose the numbers 071 and 142.

Choices punched.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

1 and 146 (sticking to my strategy from the last time)

79 (third choice)

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: Thanks for the heads up. Number (79) punched.

Answer (score 3):

I choose the numbers 16 and 116.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: My 3rd number: 65

Answer (score 3):

`29` and `129` ...............

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I choose `35` and `112`, because I'm a perfect random number generator :)

EDIT: As my third, and winning number, I chose `149` because that's better than the previous two numbers combined.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Symmetric numbers for me! 88 and 181

Third option: 13

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I will choose 14 and 44 please!

Edit: my 3rd choice is 73, as that's my average grade at university ;)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I choose `006` and `195` . . .

Edit: `182` is my third choice.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: Thanks for the information. I selected my third number. Please punch for me.

Answer (score 3):

I choose `2` because it is "one little duck" in bingo and `25` because it's "duck and dive" in bingo.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

After consulting Matlab I decided to try 192 and 126

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

`\person{127,177}{gernot}`

Though the lottery program above can't decide on the number, it tells me each time that I've won. This is a good sign, for sure.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: @PauloCereda I thank *you* for this wonderful idea.

Answer (score 3):

I choose you `7` and `107`

and...

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I'll take 111 and 171 for a lucky duck.

Thanks for the fun!

And 187 for a third.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Eleventy-one! (Or perhaps Nelson?)

Comment: @JosephWright For the Eleventy-first birthday!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I choose `120` and `130`, because people like to pick crooked numbers with 7s at the end for some reason, and I want to swim against the stream (like I give a flying duck).

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I choose:

`093`

and

`173`

and my third number is `094`

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I nominate the following three bright and shiny numbers: `61`, `62`, and `64`!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda  - Thanks! I've added "62". :-)

Answer (score 3):

`39` and `36`, which is 42 in base 11 and in base 12.

Comment: ooh an owl! `:)` Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Here are my numbers:

1st Number: **32** (current Paulo Cereda's age, according to his profile page)
2nd Number: **85** because "*LaTeX was first developed in 1985 by Leslie Lamport*" according to http://www.latex-project.org/intro.html

And yes, I understood that the numbers in the lottery will be randomly picked... but that does not mean my guesses have to be random as well! **;-)**

I already punched these two numbers in the original post **:-)**

Comment: I am getting old! `:)` Thanks for joining the contest, pal!

Comment: @PauloCereda: You're welcome :-) And thank YOU for running this Duck Giveaway again... and for everything you do for the TeX / LaTeX Community.

Comment: @PauloCereda You're very very young, enough to be my son :) ... or, from another point of view, I'm enough old to be your mother :'(

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I choose `020` and `040`, since they’re nice and symmetric.  Could some ≥2k user punch ’em for me, please?

Comment: Numbers are punched ...

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 3):

I choose `015` and `200` as the smallest and biggest numbers available.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe, 198 , 180, 189.

Good duck.

Comment: Numbers punched.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going for 162 and 193, otherwise known as ●●● and ●●●.

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I choose:

```
026
```

and

```
090
```

Comment: 3 is taken unfortunately, punched 90 though

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: Can you choose another number  instead of 3 from the table ?

Comment: I choose then 26.

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Comment: Then I pick 180!

Answer (score 2):

`89` and `51`, because 17 is best number but all to taken.

EDIT: `109` as the third, because I saw it first.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I chose the following numbers: 77 and 21

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, the time goes fast! Another year is ending.

My numbers now (I already edited the post to insert `●●●` there):

`074` and `174`.

3rd. `176`

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest! If you win, I will personally give you the duck. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda, thanks. That would be nice. Maybe I have more luck this year

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: @percusse, sorry. I didn' t follow. Is that an English expression? Were the numbers already choosen by any?

Comment: ah no just bookkeeping for whose number are already marked. we do that to all contestants

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Comment: @PauloCereda, thanks and done.

Answer (score 2):

And here I am with `017` and `113`, thank you for the nice duck!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I can haz `048` and `148` plz? Because reasons.

Third choice: `184` (I have already punched it.)

Comment: Numbers punched.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Comment: Added third number, edited post and punched it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun: `121` and `080` ...
Third number: `188`

Comment: Numbers are punched ...

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I choose `33` and `84`, and I trusted a random number generator.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: numbers punched

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll choose **49** and **144** for the two irrelevant reasons:

- It is very common to wobble something with an idiom ``Seven times seven equals 49'' in Cantonese.
- `$12\;\times\;12$` is the largest multiplication that I have learnt, and still remember.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: numbers punched

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

136 and 186, because... They're as random as every other ones 
164 added and punched! Thanks!

Comment: numbers punched

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I take 115,178:

```
\person{115,178}{Knut}
```

Comment: Numbers punched!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

011 and 197

I hope the random algorithm is really random :D

Comment: Numbers punched!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I choose 27, which is the number corresponding to 'duck' in the [Mnemonic major system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic_major_system) (and also the number of sporadic groups).

Also 95, which is the number corresponding to 'Paulo' in the MMS.

My third number is 141, because 041 (Cereda) is already taken.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: numbers punched (by whomever ...)

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

105 because it's the product of the first three odd primes.

143 because it's the product of the next two.

Third number: 114 (I think it's a stable island in the periodic table for the transuranics).

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: numbers punched (by whomever ...)

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I choose 72 and 98. My third number is 062.

Comment: number punched (by whomever ...)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

41 and 43, the only remaining pair of twin prime numbers.

Comment: (Card punched!)

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

66 and 166 because if she weighs the same as a duck... she's made of wood! (and 666 is the number of the beast and these are the closest numbers available).

[image]

(punched)

Comment: ooh a witch! `:)` Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I now pick 018 and 046 as my favorite # clashes :-D !

Comment: Thanks. I am changing it now!!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

I choose 45 and 70. Good enough for me.

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: ✓ numbers punched ✓

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

110 and 159. Just because. :-)

(punched 140 on 28 Dec because 3rd punch available!)

Comment: have now punched 110 and 159!

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest! `:)`

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Comment: ooh 140 then, punched!

Answer (score 2):

I'll chose `102` and `103`. 
Because of reasons

Comment: those are picked already. See the punch card in the question

Comment: Oh... Silly me... Editing... Sorry

Comment: Numbers Punched

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

Can I get 019 and 078? just because!

Comment: Numbers Punched

Comment: Thanks for joining the contest!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 2):

116 and 133 because I'm late and these are not taken yet.

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 1):

A duck? Damn, I just bet on some ordinary book in some other thread... :-) I hope, Fortuna is not getting overwhelmed with me when I bet some more numbers here: Let's make it

**47** and **117**

Thanks, Paulo!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 1):

For my third choice I that the first displayed palindrome  ---  060   AND I punched the number.

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are: `081`, `082` and `083`, nice lottery to everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I chose 137 and 127 and hope this are my lucky numbers

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

163 and 164 because one comes after the other!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

I choose 31 and 194, because it is the first and the last free number in this moment.

Quack, quack!

And the third number is 108: the central free in the central verse.

Quack, quack, quack!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

I choose 65 and 132, no particular reason.

Third choice: 75, fingers crossed!

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

I choose 153 and 190, because they are 18 choose 2 and 20 choose 2.

Third Number: 129

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

I will use -42 and -43 (my negative current age and my negative upcoming age ;-) ... and -44

Comment: No need to punch ;-)

Comment: It is now possible to pick a third number! Hurry! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll take 165 for my third number

Answer (score 0):

I'll take 106 as my third number.