# Help me to find a topic for the next DuckBoat!

Tags: discussion, fun

You know that the DuckBoats usually have two parts.

The first one "Quacking in chat" is about TeX.SE news and similar topics, till now:

- the double backslash problem
- origin and evolution of duck mania
- upvoting behavior
- "Cinderella" topics.

Whereas the second one is a Quack Guide for beginners about some LaTeX package or TeX.SE feature.

For the next issue, in the first part, I wanted to talk about [What NOT to do when you're trying to help a newbie?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8123/what-not-to-do-when-youre-trying-to-help-a-newbie), but Sarah Lang and Astrid Schmölzer were faster than me (see their article in TUG 40:1, 2019).

So I run out of ideas, please help me!

Comment: Academic integrity/efficient way to handle `just-do-it-for-me` questions?

Comment: Strategies for finding previous questions on the same topic?  (The "often referenced questions" question on meta might be cited, and I encourage anyone who finds a really good question/answer that isn't there already to add it.)

Comment: @Raaja Thank you, a very hot topic!

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, good idea!

Comment: The first wild-born pups of this year are out on Vancouver Island. ;-)

Comment: @marmot Lovely but a bit off-topic :)

Comment: Well, maybe you could rethink this. Just imagine the nice pictures you could add. ;-)

Comment: @CarLaTeX you are welcome!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I appreciate your work and effort! It's only the duck-way I struggle with, seeing it in a printed journal too after it's been kind of a running joke in the chat over years. Please continue contributing.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz I appreciate your effort in writing your comment and I know Barbara is worried because there is not a better replacement for the DuckBoats, but they clearly dividing. Your answer got 10 downvotes and 7 upvotes, plus yours they are 8.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz What about if you write a column for the beginners?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I could be challenged in a way. Each time that the master mind behind Prof. van Duck adds another tutorial article without duck costume (so that time for the non-duck-compatible users), I would send an article myself too.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz "the master mind behind prof. van Duck"? Are you suggesting that he's just a hand puppet?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I would choose the word *pseudonym*, and that as a wild guess.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz To tell the true, he _is_ a hand puppet: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/the-duck-giveaway-2016-seasonal-edition

Comment: @Downvoters could you care to explain why this question is down-voted?

Comment: @Raaja I think some users are annoyed by the duck invasion. Some time ago you could not join the chat without seeing a duck joke, it was too much. Hence, some users can't stand to see ducks around again.

Comment: @CarLaTeX that should not a reason for down-vote for a proper question.

Comment: @Raaja Downvoting in Meta is a little bit different than on the main site, it means also "I disagree" :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX though that is understandable, it strikes me with a new question. Is downvoting the right way to show disapproval in meta? :D but I still think the downvoter must defend their action ;)

Comment: @Raaja Yes, in general it is fair to say why you downvote, unless it is absolutely clear, like for spam post and similar.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I agree with you :)

Answer (score 10):

I would like to propose: Academic integrity/efficient way to handle `just-do-it-for-me` questions.

Answer (score 8):

The professore could chat about quite a number of open questions/events:

- the tikzlings visit to france.
- tikzlings quantum physics: is the dead `\cat[schroedinger]`  entangled with a laughing or a crying mouse?
- why is tikzducks a separate package (https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings/issues/8)
- What does a Professore from Brazil and now living in Milan think about tourists wanting Hawaii and Nutella pizza at the winter olympic games in 2026?
- how to create deja-vu chains in the chat?
- should tikzlings be in a beginners introduction? (Naturally, they are friendly and good tutors ;-))
- and for tex users in the humanities he could chat about language and script skills in the chat.

Answer (score 7):

A useful area centered on tex.sx could be strategies for finding previous questions on the same topic.

There's a posting on tex.meta entitled "Often referenced questions":  `https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2419`.  This is cumulative (I add to it whenever I find a particularly good question/answer in an area that isn't already covered, and encourage others to do so as well).
It's a sure bet that newbies don't know about this, and probably many tex.sx "regulars" don't either.

Somewhat off-topic.  This link just fell into my in-box, and addresses the concern of whether animal references are "professional" when applied to serious topics:
https://twitter.com/dr_know/status/1146399929138630656?utm_source=Nature+Briefing

Comment: Thank you Barbara, very interesting link! With very interesting comments!