# Who Wants to Win another LaTeX Book?

Tags: discussion, publicity

I am organising yet another lottery and Springer have kindly agreed to donate two copies of [*LaTeX and Friends*](http://csweb.ucc.ie/~dongen/LAF/LAF.html) (see [also](http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4)).

This year I decided to be the judge of the lottery. The lottery closes when the judge has announced the last winner. The judge's decision is final and there shall be no discussion and/or correspondence about the outcome of the lottery.

To win the book you may guess **two numbers** in the range 1--250. The first two people that guess the right number win a copy of the book. Please note that the time of arrival in TeX-SX is what counts, not the time of sending.

To give everybody a fair chance, you may submit only one number.

There is one exception to the previous rule. If several contestants submit the same number, the contestant whose submission arrived first is valid. The other contestants may resubmit a new number.

Contestants must have been a member of TeX-SX before 10 December, 2014. (Without this restriction, people may start creating fake accounts and submit multiple guesses.)

Please post your guess as **an answer to this meta question**; **not** as a comment. Comments will be ignored. Please only put your guess in the body of the answer.

Guesses will be checked every couple of days and the winner will be announced within a few days after.

I can sign the book at your request. Please note that I won't sign by default because I know some people want to keep their books pencil and ink free.

**At the time of writing there were no winners yet. To speed things up, contestants may choose two numbers in total.**

** OK It's two days before Christmas and the remaining number still hasn't been guessed. I'm giving you one more try, so everybody may guess three numbers in total. **

**Update: the numbers were 126 and 197 have been guessed by [mrf](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/11709/mrf) and [phollox](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/users/50886/phollox) respectively**.

Congratulations to Winners !. Thanks all for participating. More luck next year.

```
    -----------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|129|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|140|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|148|149|◖■◗| 
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |151|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|155|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|160|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|164|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗| 
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |191|◖■◗|◖■◗|194|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|207|◖■◗|209|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|095|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|230| 
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------
    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|    |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
    -----------------------------------------    -----------------------------------------

                        -----------------------------------------
                        |◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|◖■◗|
                        -----------------------------------------

Copy/paste card punch : |◖■◗|
```

Having difficulty getting by the [trivial answer checker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98950) (due to including an internal site link, perhaps)? Include this 2x2 pixel image at the end of your guess:

```
![trivial answer checker avoidance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRgZB.png)
```

Comment: **People, I don't understand you I think. We've got 14 people wanting a book, and only 6 of them grateful to Marc for organizing this little TeX.SX Xmas? ...**

Comment: @tohecz To be fair, the customary way of saying 'thanks' on this site is to vote posts up and, by that reckoning, 35 people have said 'thanks', while 52 have answered. Assuming that only those who have answered have voted up, that's slightly better...

Comment: And people – please stop shaming the 'uninteresting' numbers. [All numbers are interesting!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox)

Comment: @SeanAllred Isn't there even *one* uninteresting number? Seems a shame - I'd be interested to know which one it was.

Comment: I have the book Marc. I want to give others an opportunity hence would pass on this. Thanks for every year lottery at tex.sx.

Comment: @texenthusiast Thanks for that.

Comment: Thanks again for this generous donation to the community. I'm sure we all appreciate it!

Comment: I'm going to lock here to 'preserve' the question/answers as-is. If anyone needs to edit, ping me in the chat room.

Answer (score 13):

37. Because:

    - It's prime!
    - It's your body temperature in degrees Celsius.
    - 37 * 2 - 1 = 73 (and this is the only number that does this in base 10)

      (and btw, 73 is prime as well)
    - AND it's a centered hexagonal number (take sides of 4 dots):

      [image]
    - AND it's a star number (take sides of 3 dots):

      [image]

Oh, and it has its own website as well: http://thirty-seven.org/

Comment: This answer is great!

Answer (score 9):

My choice is **247** because tex.se has a 24/7 service!
My another two guesses are **60** and **195**.

[image]
[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 8):

041
**197**
[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

[image: picture of pie]

Comment: Congratulations: 197 is one of the two numbers I picked. Please give me your snail mail details and I'll send the book as soon as I have it (it's still on its way from the publisher). Do you want me to sign the book.

Comment: Amazing!!! Merry Christmas to me. Can I post my address here? I meant, is it safe?

Comment: I sent you an email to the address in your website. Thanks again

Comment: @phollox For future reference, your address would be as safe here as it would be if posted simultaneously on the bulletin board of every grocery store in the world :)  The great majority of people would pay no mind, but…

Comment: Oh! And congrats!

Comment: Nothing can beat the power of a pie! `:)` Congrats and merry Christmas! `:)`

Comment: @sean yes, I realized that after I asked. But anyway, what's the worst thing that could happen? Don't answer... A "friend" wanted to sent me a box with 1000 live crickets. And that's not even close to a really bad thing. Thanks !!

Answer (score 7):

I'll take 154 because the ISBN for the hardcover version of *LaTeX and Friends* ends with these digits.

Answer (score 7):

[The same every year;](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3030/3235) I go with 131

[image]

Answer (score 6):

42, the Answer to Life, the Universe and Everything.

Answer (score 6):

**251**

I was going to re-use the number from last year but I see you changed the rules, you don't trick me that easily, so it's a new number this year.

**502**

Second number is twice the first and has exactly twice the chance of winning.

**1004**

because it's twice my last guess.

Comment: Updated for 2nd number

Answer (score 5):

My choice is 123, for the same reason I like vanilla ice cream.
And 202.
And 044.

Answer (score 5):

**119**, because that's what LaTeX told me to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    The random number I chose is
    \tikz{\pgfmathsetmacro\x{round(rnd*249+1)}\node at (0,0) {\x}}
\end{document}
```

As a second guess, I take **138** - same reason as before.

As third guess I'll try **102** for no specific reason.

PS: thanks to @percusse for your suggestion, i wasn't aware of this possibility.

Comment: `The random number I chose is \pgfmathparse{round(rnd*249+1)}\pgfmathresult` ;)

Answer (score 4):

64. that's `2^6`, a good binary power.

and i'd welcome a signed copy, should the unlikely happen.

**edit** thank you for the extension.  227 for a second number.

**edit 2** another extension!  107.

Answer (score 4):

009 Peer pressured into thinking of a reason. Identifier of the simulations I'm analysing.

Answer (score 4):

My Guess:  135.  Because it's one more than 134.

Second choice:  199.  Because it's 65 more than 134.

Answer (score 4):

147, a maximum break in snooker.

Comment: +1 for snooker!

Answer (score 4):

**239**

(the largest prime still available)

Answer (score 3):

I'll go with

- 3
- 174
- 177

Answer (score 3):

I will go with 233, that's the largest Fibonacci number in the sheet. PS: If it's me, then signed please :)

Second guess: `◖■◗` I mean, `093` :)

Third guess: `211`

Answer (score 3):

87 (my current rep modulo 1000)

Second number: 16 (the smallest free one)

Third number: 240 (the highest free one)

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 3):

I choose 24, because why not :) !

Answer (score 3):

193. Because it's just as good as any other.

Answer (score 3):

26, my day of birth, and a number I usually encounter in pleasant circumstances. [image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

My second choice is the number 61.

My third choice is 226.

Answer (score 3):

### 19

because:

The sum of the first 250 integers: `(1+250)*250/2=31375`

The sum of the digits of 31375: `3+1+3+7+5=19` (and it's prime, and everyone loves prime numbers `;)` )

### 231

as my second choice

P.S. If it's me, then I would gladly welcome a signature `;)`

Thank you.

### 168

as my third choice. Thanks again `:)`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer 8. And although I know I don't have to say "thank you" I do. Thank you.

Second choice: 175

Third choice: 40

Answer (score 3):

004

It's random, so if you pick anything but the first available number you are not a mathematician ;)
[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Comment: +1 for snark :)

Answer (score 3):

**77**

**EDIT 1: 122**

**EDIT 2: 49**

Some more useless text so the system stops complaining.

Answer (score 3):

216, because it's 6 cubed.  Lots of small factors.

Answer (score 3):

`013`. (I don't think it is gone.) Thanks very much for going to the trouble of organising this. [I would like to know - afterwards - how you selected the numbers.]

I cannot write the number without putting it in code?

Second number: 242.

Third number: 217.

Comment: I generated them with a random number generator. (Sorry, I don't know the initial seed.)

Answer (score 3):

229, because it is 1729 modulo 250. And 1729 is SO famous and beautiful number...

**Edit**

And the second is 172, because it is 1729 divided by 10 (in TeX counters sense).

Comment: It only takes a [Ramanujan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1729_%28number%29) to see that in a flash.

Comment: Interestingly linked to by the [interesting number article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interesting_number_paradox) I posted to the Q far before I knew why 1729 was "SO famous" :)

Answer (score 3):

208 (Yes, I have read *all* the other answers)

and second guess 038 as the currently lowest available remaining

A third guess before the new year: 139 (somewhere between the other two)

Answer (score 3):

173 is mine! Simply because I threw a dart at my screen and that is where it landed. Also, awesome event! Oh, if I would be the lucky one, I would love a signature!

Answer (score 3):

020 because I hope to have a first version of my thesis ready by the 20th :-)

And 218, for no special reason.

Comment: good luck with your thesis!

Comment: @samcarter Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

184, because I have a strong intuition.

Answer (score 3):

163, as per my wife's suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

14, for 'tis my age! Thanks for organising such an event, Marc! :)

P.S: A signed copy would be appreciated! :)

**Edit:** Second number is 15, ta!

**Edit:** Hey, me again! I'll have a shot with 062, cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

**81**

I am going for 81 = 9 x 9

Answer (score 3):

136, because the ground state energy of the hydrogen atom is -13.6 eV.

Answer (score 3):

How about **192**, because my birthday falls on the 192nd day of the year.

Edit: since a second number is allowed, I was going to choose 158 (since that's the number of days since my birthday to today), but somebody else seems to have chosen that. So how about **159**, since nobody has that yet.

Answer (score 3):

I go for **63**, the *only* Mersenne number whose prime divisors all appear in the factorization of previous Mersenne numbers.

...and for the **32**: number of faces of the truncated icosahedron. Soccer rules! :)

Answer (score 3):

**157** and **203**

Because these were first two non-taken results from

```
$ python

import random
print random.randint(0, 251)
```

Answer (score 2):

My three numbers are

- 7
- 249
- 109

Answer (score 2):

241 please - highest prime in the list.

And since you have kindly invited us to choose a second, I'll take 53 as well please (another prime, but also connected with an event in 1962).  And by the way, thank you very much for your kind offer!

Answer (score 2):

**Update 1:** I picked a number which was already taken, so I got 220 now. `:)`

**Update 2:** My second guess: 110 (the sum of three consecutive squares).

**Update 3:** My third guess: 115 because pie. `:)`

Comment: Hmmm... [1 was already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5808/5764).

Comment: @Werner: was it? Oh my, I'm stoopid. `:)`

Comment: @Werner: I got 220, let's see if nobody else took it. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

[Random.org](http://random.org) says: 90

Answer (score 2):

57 (first two digits of the question identifier)

83 (my second choice)

219 (third choice)

Answer (score 2):

I choose **245** (well, my wife did to me).

**Edit:**

Ow, just now I discovered that we can choose 2 numbers.

So my second one is **146** because now is 21:46.

**Edit 2**

So the 3rd number I choose is **058**.

Answer (score 2):

I choose 69. Just because. `:P`

Second guess: 43, because it is the next largest prime number compared to the answer to life and everything. :)

And finally 124, because... well because it's the third possibility!

Answer (score 2):

I will go for 2. I like this number.

My secong guess is 130.

Answer (score 2):

128. because seven bits gives 128 ASCII characters.

Answer (score 2):

The number of pages in my most recent LaTeX run was **54**, so that’s what I’m choosing.

ETA: Second guess is **246**.

Answer (score 2):

27, because I like that number :)

Answer (score 2):

143, for no reason. 
051, also no reason
161, still no reason

Answer (score 2):

101. 

Answer (score 2):

59, because it was 8:59 when I was writing this.

Comment: Something's wrong here; it was 1:59 when you posted it ;) :p

Comment: @tohecz Then I guess you are probably in Europe, aren't you? My local time in China was just that. :)

Comment: Yes I am ... :)

Answer (score 2):

127, cause that was the time I started writing.

**EDIT 2nd Number**
180 because Roman Emperor, Marcus Aurelius died on 17 March(yaaaa, St. Patricks Day!) 180AD.

**Edit 3rd Number**
078

Answer (score 2):

30, because .... well .... 30.

Second choice: 33

Third choice: 223

Answer (score 2):

My choice is for 22 (number of a famous brasilian football player in AC Milan few years ago).

Comment: Is Kaká? Maybe!

Comment: @Sigur: Correct, indeed!!!

Answer (score 2):

21, 35, 56

… seems like an OK number to me :)  Send Springer our thanks!  Hopefully this will make resource more popular – printed copies are always easier to truly learn from :)

-- Seems like 21+35=56 was the only real option here. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's 23, of course. All hail Eris!

Answer (score 2):

My answer is 238 because it seemed like a good idea at the time.

Answer (score 2):

34. The minute I posted this (just to generate a random number)

**Edit** The second number is 204 (just because it is still free)

**Third guess** 167

Answer (score 2):

121

...because it's an integer.

Take two: **103** because it has the same sum of digits as 121.

Third time Lucky: **060**

Answer (score 2):

  137.

I won't get this any way.

Answer (score 2):

memory’s failing, and going through the list of significant dates only comes up with **28**

Answer (score 2):

I guess 17, cause 17 is my day of birth

Answer (score 2):

190, because that's the only one worthy of being a number ;) Second choice: 099 (but I am too soft!)

Answer (score 2):

141, first (3-digit) consecutive digits of Pi available.

Answer (score 2):

I choose 205, it's similar to my lucky number

Answer (score 2):

206

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll go with **071**.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to pick the number 31.

Answer (score 2):

- 1st number: 215
- 2nd number: 214

Answer (score 2):

236 because my system time displays the same :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I take **010**, because the random number generator said so.

Now that two guesses are allowed, my other choice is **066**.

My third guess is **178**.

Answer (score 2):

**12**, because it's the reciprocal of the opposite of the [sum of all natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Answer (score 2):

075
No reason.

076
Because it's next to my first guess. Think [Battleship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) ...

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 2):

176 = 2^4 x 11, and I would love to have it signed by you!
Thanks a lot and greetings to Springer :).

Answer (score 2):

186 plus some other characters to make up the body length limit.

Second guess: 6

And a third guess: 188

Answer (score 2):

96 (And now my character count > 30.)

Answer (score 2):

248, because it is 2^1 2^2 2^3

second guess is 244, because it looks nice.

Third guess: 221

Thanks a lot for preparing this contest! In the improbable case of winning the book, a signed one would be the icing on the cake!

Answer (score 2):

108. A spiritual number, they say.

Answer (score 2):

70 because it's the 70th answer

Comment: Well I think it is based on time!

Answer (score 2):

113                           .

Answer (score 2):

I guess 144, because 144 = 12 * 12 = 3^2*2^4

Answer (score 2):

72, cause its neat and I seem to get it often.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is 158. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Thank you!

My second number is going to be: 074

Answer (score 2):

116. Because I can, and because it was the first thing I gazed upon.

Answer (score 2):

243.
[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 2):

111 :D
Because is cool and because is...111

Answer (score 2):

120, because it is not caught yet.

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 2):

**47**, my dice said so

Second quess: **181** (no dice)

Third guess! **230**

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Comment: A 47+-sided dice?

Comment: @nyuszika7h Three 10-sided dice.

Answer (score 2):

`084`, the year of the first release of Knuth's Tex book.

Second guess: `052`, just one of the remaining choices.

Answer (score 2):

117. Who knows? [image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 2):

1, just because it's too simple to choose.

Answer (score 2):

097.
Because, for me, it is yellow.

Answer (score 2):

I would like 212 and 222, because that is an awesome number too!

If one of these is a lucky number, I would love an autograph!

Answer (score 2):

007.

```
\begin{overly used quote}My name is Bond...\end{overly used quote}
```

Oh -- seven is taken already. 234 then.

Answer (score 2):

I'll take 232.

Because of [RS232](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232).

Answer (score 2):

65. A common U.S. retiring age.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like **152** hasn't been taken yet.

If someone scoops me, I'll go with **45**.

Thanks for offering this lottery!

Answer (score 2):

048, 086, and 183 (random number generator)

Answer (score 2):

My two guesses:

073 and 142

Answer (score 2):

120 - its 5!, the symmetry of the icosahedron and of the pentachoron.  The  largest of the six polyopes in 4D has 120 faces, and ispend a good dealof time getting LaTeX to work in base 120

|◖■◗|

Answer (score 2):

My guesses are:
132 133 134

Because this was the only consecutive triple left on the same row.

Answer (score 2):

My three guesses:
**55 Lowest remaining

235 Highest remaining

145 Average of the previous two**

(55 + 235)/2 = 145

Answer (score 2):

My first and only attempt is 079, 080, 092!

Answer (score 1):

179 without a valid reason. I'm sure it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If no one has taken 5 yet, I shall

Answer (score 1):

165, because I feel it will be the winning number.

I will appreciate a signed copy.

Answer (score 1):

18 because it's pretty much the best number.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, I will win 011<sub>2</sub> = 3<sub>10</sub> books :)

Answer (score 1):

I choose 68 and 112

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 1):

I choose **82** and **171** because they both look good in formal attire.

Answer (score 1):

237. All the cool ones were already taken.
     Since I can pick two, let's go for 118, the current number of elements in the periodic table.

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 1):

25 + 29 = `\hrule`[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Comment: So you're choosing 25 *and* 29, not 25+29=54, since [54 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5724/5764)...

Comment: Oh, yes, that was the plan. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

First number: **25** because... **XXV** is related to this "Latex and Friends" book :-) See http://www.springer.com/computer/media+design/book/978-3-642-23815-4

Second number: **85** because "*LaTeX was first developed in 1985 by Leslie Lamport*" - according to http://www.latex-project.org/intro.html

**UPDATE (23-dec-2014):** So we can now add a Third number? That's great! I'm adding **94** because LaTeX2e was released in 1994 - http://latex-project.org/ltnews/ltnews01.pdf

I also participated in the last time - https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/13063 - and didn't win. So I **have** to win this time. Right?! ;-)

**EDIT:** In the off chance that I **do** win, I would love that the book came signed/autographed.

Many Thanks to Marc van Dongen and Springer for making this possible.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is 196.  I tried to check, and I believe the number has not yet been taken.  Also is is a square, has 7 as a prime factor and the number is larger than my age in years, so this must be it!

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Comment: This was off by 1 :(  And I thought my argument was fool-proof ...

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with 224 and 225. Not that I expect anything more than a lump of coal in my stocking.

Edit: Since you now kindly give us **three** guesses, like a proper djinni, I'll pick 126 for my third guess.

[image]

Comment: Congratulations: *126* is a winner. Please send me oyur contact details and I'll send you the book. Do you want it signed?

Answer (score 1):

I guess 105 and 198, because numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like 67 and 185.
[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 1):

101 and 5 [image]

Answer (score 1):

21, because nobody is guessing low numbers!

edit: and 11

Answer (score 1):

I will try with the numbers 039 and 169.

Answer (score 1):

36 and 125

[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Answer (score 1):

First guess: **65**

Second guess: **237**

Because `python3 -c 'from random import *;print(randint(1, 250), randint(1, 250))'` says so.

Answer (score 1):

My selection is the following: 050 and 156

Answer (score 1):

091, or 91, the only number less than 100 that looks like a prime but isn't.

Second number 100, for no particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

<s>71 and</s> 46 chosen by random number generator. I've checked, **153** is still available!

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are the following: 38 and 166.

Answer (score 1):

213  because 13 was used by another one

and

088  no special reason, just for fun!

Third guess: 201!

Answer (score 1):

**089** and **189**,

because I'm born in 1989.

And **170**,

highest finish in darts.

Answer (score 1):

98, maybe just because is 97 + 1?

Answer (score 1):

My guesses shall be 104, 106, and 228.

Answer (score 1):

My guesses are 114, 162, and 182.

Answer (score 0):

187
210
30
[image: trivial answer checker avoidance]

Comment: [30 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5732/5764).

Answer (score 0):

47
152
17

(No reason.  Just going by whatever my gut says.  (Why should I trust my gut, though?))

Comment: [47 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5798/5764).

Comment: [152 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5816/5764).

Comment: [17 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5747/5764).

Comment: OK.  I lose. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the remaining primes in [100, 110]: 101, 103, and 109.

Comment: [101 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5829/5764).

Comment: [103 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5742/5764).

Comment: [109 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5706/5764).

Answer (score 0):

1st guess: 108

2nd guess: 142

3rd guess: 242

Comment: [142 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5852/5764).

Comment: [242 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5758/5764).

Comment: [108 is already taken](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/5775/5764).